# Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags

Tags: jquery, text, tags

If I have html like this:

```
<li id="listItem">
    This is some text
    <span id="firstSpan">First span text</span>
    <span id="secondSpan">Second span text</span>
</li>
```

I'm trying to use `.text()` to retrieve just the string "This is some text", but if I were to say `$('#list-item').text()`, I get "This is some textFirst span textSecond span text".

Is there a way to get (and possibly remove, via something like `.text("")`) just the free text within a tag, and not the text within its child tags?

The HTML was not written by me, so this is what I have to work with. I know that it would be simple to just wrap the text in tags when writing the html, but again, the html is pre-written.

Comment: Because I do not have enough reputation yet to comment and I do not wish the knowledge to be lost (hopefully it helps someone else), a combination of [macio.Jun' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14755309/3662499), a RegExp, and [iStranger' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42008274/3662499) to [Replace a textNode with HTML in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553280/replace-a-textnode-with-html-text-in-javascript) allowed me to search text-only nodes for a string and replace all occurrences with links.

Answer (score 567, accepted):

I liked this reusable implementation based on the `clone()` method found [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/) to get only the text inside the parent element.

Code provided for easy reference:

```
$("#foo")
    .clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text();
```

Comment: With this solution you only get the text without the child, but you can't replace only the text.

Comment: I don't get 1 thing: If .end() goes back to selected element, than text() should copy original text with children elements. But in practice I see that text from our manipulated clone is being copied. So end() goes back to clone() ?

Comment: This is a really inefficient way of doing this

Comment: @billyonecan, can you suggest a more efficient method? This is appealing because it is "clean" and "short". What do you suggest?

Comment: @derekmx271 have a look at [Stuart's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags/8851526#answer-3442757)

Comment: Definitely easiest and most creative solution, how about the performance, though? Probably quite ineffective and slow?

Comment: Should work perfectly but slow. I wonder if one could remove children of actual element, get text, and then re-add them back.

Comment: This would be a very bad solution if you had to process every node in a large html document and retrieve the text for each node because cloning every node would be senseless.

Comment: See my solution: it does the same thing, but is much faster (no DOM manipulation)

Comment: @billyonecan please don't do premature optimization... Readable code is more important than saving a few milliseconds once in a while...

Comment: It is lacking a $.trim() call. Otherwise very clean! Thank you!

Comment: @LidelnKyoku can you explain how cloning the element, traversing all of its children, removing them, adding the cloned element back to the stack, and then getting its text is more readable than simply accessing the property directly? your comment makes no sense

Comment: [Here's the corrected link to Stuart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags/#3442757)

Comment: @billyonecan just because you are describing each step with several words, which makes it long to read, has nothing to do with the solution itself. It is concise, readable, easily understandable. Plus, your first comment was talking about efficiency, to which I replied, but now you are switching to a completely different topic. As for Stuart's answer, that you seem to acclaim, it does not seem to work for me. I don't know what more you want... I upvoted the answer that actually did work. What is wrong with that?

Comment: @billyonecan actually after some effort I managed to make it work. But I will still use the jQuery chained calls solution. Why? Because it is generic. The solution offered by Stuart, which is fine too, presents two issues to me: first it requires knowledge of the vanilla javascript DOM API, which jQuery allows us to abstract from, and second because it requires to access the node by index, which means everytime your HTML markup evolves, your JS code breaks. Thanks but no thanks.

Comment: My point is that, in order to understand this solution, you need to know what those 5 different methods are doing, but also why they need to do it. I fail to see how that's more readable than just accessing the property directly or, in your case if you're concerned about the markup changing, just directly filtering out the text nodes (why start cloning elements and removing elements when all you need is some text?). If you find that this is more readable than other solutions, that's fine. I never said there was anything wrong with upvoting it.

Comment: This make the job!

Comment: This is a bit ridiculous to do this much operations with jQuery just to parse a string.  Let's not forget HTML is just a string, easily parsed, no jQuery needed for that part.

Comment: @OGSean You can't parse HTML code with a regular expression. Theoretically proved.

Comment: @billyonecan "Just access directly" does not work as it depends on the fixed index 0. **Your suggestion is dangerous.** What if the unnested text nodes are shattered throughout the element? What if a non-text-node takes the index 0? You got to list child nodes, filter out text nodes, map them to string literals, and join, to do what this solution does. That is long enough with a bunch of arrow functions, longer than this solution. And as for performance, I don't mind because my computer does this in a few nanoseconds.

Answer (score 416):

Simple answer:

```
$("#listItem").contents().filter(function(){ 
  return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE; 
})[0].nodeValue = "The text you want to replace with"
```

If for some reason you have to support Internet Explorer below version 8, you have to use `3` instead of `Node.TEXT_NODE`.

Comment: I don't understand why efficient answers (that dont generate extraneous data structures) are not voted up as much as answers that look less scary. +5 if I could.

Comment: This is not only more efficient but also correct!
This solution caters for situations when the text is scattered between child elements. +5

Comment: This will break if you use it on something with no text. If you're using this as a function and have a scenario where you may or may not have text, just capture the `.contents().filter(...)` call into a local variable and check its length, e.g., 
`var text = $(this).contents().filter(...); if (text.length) { return text[0].nodeValue; } return "";`

Comment: as @CarlBussema said, this implementaion is NOT null-safe. to avoid this serious issue, DO NOT use `[0].nodeValue` directly.

Comment: This worked amazingly well within a container that had other elements that get changed dynamically. Thanks Macio!

Comment: Having an element before the text might cause you to have to use .last() after .filter(...) in case there are line breaks on the html, otherwise [0] will just return a linebreak. If you have mixed elements and a text node it will get messy, will be easier to fix your html and put your text inside a span or div with a class

Comment: @CarlBussema to avoid null scenarios, why not just do `$("#listItem").contents().filter(function(){ 
  return this.nodeType == 3; 
}).text()` to retrieve the text? Why mess about with `nodeValue` at all?

Comment: @StevenLu You answered yourself. If it's simpler/easier to understand and still works, that's the one people will upvote. And I don't think that's necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: This will only replace the first text node. You will probably get unexpected results for things like `<div> this is replaced <b> this is not </b> but neither is this </div>`.
Also note the first node could be only whitespace. e.g.
`<div>\n\t\t <b>this is not replaced</b> this neither</div>`.

Answer (score 225):

This seems like a case of overusing jquery to me. The following will grab the text ignoring the other nodes:

```
document.getElementById("listItem").childNodes[0];
```

You'll need to trim that but it gets you what you want in one, easy line.

**EDIT**

The above will get the *text node*.  To get the actual text, use this:

```
document.getElementById("listItem").childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Comment: Best answer, you're not supposed to need a plugin for this or a chain of 10 jQuery calls. `$('.foo')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim()`

Comment: what if the text content is split up into several nodes (like a sequence of crlf, text, crlf)? are there any (rael-life) guarantees that the dom constructed by the ua will use the simplest structure ?

Comment: Totally the best answer... why other people sometimes over use jQuery?

Comment: Maybe to avoid having to take care of cross browser compatibility?

Comment: ok, best idea for a now, but for me nodeValuethis doesnt work. work textContent but this pull all content, any other suggestion in vanilla ?

Comment: best answer I think ，more natrual

Comment: This only works in the case of <div id="listItem">text you want<span>other</span></div>.  It will not work for <div id="listItem"><span>other</span>text you want</div>

Comment: Actually folks Spencer's comment illustrates why macio.Jun's jQuery solution will often be best (with the caveat that you add a null check)

Comment: @collapsar in my case I had to iterate through two concatenated text strings, which were delimitted by an "\n", so it was pretty easy to var target = textString.split("\n") and then get target[0].

Comment: I wish I could do a plus 10 to this answer. Best answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Sometimes you don't have `document`. Came here using `cheerio`.

Comment: if i replace something from `nodeValue` how can i ?

Comment: **This is dangerous.** What if the first child is not a text node?

Comment: @КонстантинВан I totally agree with you.

Comment: To clarify what I said: jQuery/Cheerio’s `.text()` does more job than this simple property access. It actually _joins_ the `.textContents` of _all_ the child nodes — that way it doesn’t break, when one day other stuff randomly gets added to the HTML code and pushing your elements around. For this plain Javascript approach to do the same in a foolproof manner, you need to `.filter` out the unwanted first and make sure it is the text node you’re looking for.

Answer (score 82):

Easier and quicker:

```
$("#listItem").contents().get(0).nodeValue
```

Comment: Is this cross browser compatible ?

Comment: Of course it retrieves one of the elements matched by the jQuery object given by the index: [Jquery Docs .get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

Comment: @Nate In case you need use it on a <br/> tag you could use the [macio.Jun](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14755309/3353403/)'s answer.

Comment: Why `get(0)` instead of just `[0]`?

Comment: Fails on    `<div id="listItem">
     <div>Contents?</div>
     Text? What text?
    </div>`

Answer (score 48):

Similar to the accepted answer, but without cloning:

```
$("#foo").contents().not($("#foo").children()).text();
```

And here is a jQuery plugin for this purpose:

```
$.fn.immediateText = function() {
    return this.contents().not(this.children()).text();
};
```

Here is how to use this plugin:

```
$("#foo").immediateText(); // get the text without children
```

Comment: What is t in t.children()?

Comment: This is a duplicate solution of the one that pbjk wrote in Jan'15... nonetheless - it looks nice.

Comment: Not really, @Oskar. The `.contents()` part is critical here!

Comment: Bad solution if your nodes don't use ids.

Comment: @AndroidDev You can always replace the selector with whatever works for you. This is just to illustrate the technique!
I also added a Plugin version to show that it works even without IDs

Comment: You get my upvote for the jQuery plugin - a very elegant solution to tackle it in the most generic & usable way.

Answer (score 8):

isn't the code:

```
var text  =  $('#listItem').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

just becoming jQuery for jQuery's sake? When simple operations involve that many chained commands & that much (unnecessary) processing, perhaps it is time to write a jQuery extension:

```
(function ($) {
    function elementText(el, separator) {
        var textContents = [];
        for(var chld = el.firstChild; chld; chld = chld.nextSibling) {
            if (chld.nodeType == 3) { 
                textContents.push(chld.nodeValue);
            }
        }
        return textContents.join(separator);
    }
    $.fn.textNotChild = function(elementSeparator, nodeSeparator) {
    if (arguments.length<2){nodeSeparator="";}
    if (arguments.length<1){elementSeparator="";}
        return $.map(this, function(el){
            return elementText(el,nodeSeparator);
        }).join(elementSeparator);
    }
} (jQuery));
```

to call:

```
var text = $('#listItem').textNotChild();
```

the arguments are in case a different scenario is encountered, such as

```
<li>some text<a>more text</a>again more</li>
<li>second text<a>more text</a>again more</li>

var text = $("li").textNotChild(".....","<break>");
```

text will have value:

```
some text<break>again more.....second text<break>again more
```

Comment: Nice. How about making this a pull request for the next version of jQuery?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
$('#listItem').not($('#listItem').children()).text()
```

Comment: This looks simply wrong.

Answer (score 6):

It'll need to be something tailored to the needs, which are dependent on the structure you're presented with. For the example you've provided, this works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var $tmp = $('#listItem').children().remove();
     $('#listItem').text('').append($tmp);
});
```

Demo: http://jquery.nodnod.net/cases/2385/run

But it's fairly dependent on the markup being similar to what you posted.

Comment: Future reader beware: the code in this answer kills the children in the actual element. One should use the `clone` method here if that's not the intended effect.

Comment: @DotNetWala's answer, below, and should be used instead of this one. 
Or at the least, use the `.detach()` method instead of `.remove()`.

Answer (score 5):

If the position `index` of the text node is fixed among its siblings, you can use

```
$('parentselector').contents().eq(index).text()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$($('#listItem').contents()[0]).text()
```

Short variant of [Stuart answer.](/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags/3442757#3442757)

or with `get()`

```
$($('#listItem').contents().get(0)).text()
```

Answer (score 4):

I presume this would be a fine solution also - if you want to get contents of all text nodes that are direct children of selected element.

```
$(selector).contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 3; }).text();
```

Note: jQuery documentation uses similar code to explain contents function: https://api.jquery.com/contents/

P.S. There's also a bit uglier way to do that, but this shows more in depth how things work, and allows for custom separator between text nodes (maybe you want a line break there)

```
$(selector).contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 3; }).map(function() { return this.nodeValue; }).toArray().join("");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery.fn.ownText = function () {
    return $(this).contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
    }).text();
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but the top answer is very inefficient. Here's a better solution:

```
$.fn.myText = function() {
    var str = '';

    this.contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType == 3) {
            str += this.textContent || this.innerText || '';
        }
    });

    return str;
};
```

And just do this:

```
$("#foo").myText();
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother with jQuery for this, *especially* not the solutions that make unnecessary clones of the elements. A simple loop grabbing text nodes is all you need. In modern JavaScript (as of this writing — "modern" is a moving target!) and trimming whitespace from the beginning and end of the result:

```
const { childNodes } = document.getElementById("listItem");
let text = "";
for (const node of childNodes) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        text += node.nodeValue;
    }
}
text = text.trim();
```

Live Example:

```js
const { childNodes } = document.getElementById("listItem");
let text = "";
for (const node of childNodes) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        text += node.nodeValue;
    }
}
console.log(text);
```

```html
<li id="listItem">
    This is some text
    <span id="firstSpan">First span text</span>
    <span id="secondSpan">Second span text</span>
</li>
```

Some people would use `reduce` for this. I'm not a fan, I think a simple loop is clearer, but this usage does update the accumulator on each iteration, so it's not actually *abusing* `reduce`:

```
const { childNodes } = document.getElementById("listItem");
const text = [...childNodes].reduce((text, node) =>
    node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ? text + node.nodeValue : text
, "").trim();
```

```js
const { childNodes } = document.getElementById("listItem");
const text = [...childNodes].reduce((text, node) =>
    node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ? text + node.nodeValue : text
, "").trim();
console.log(text);
```

```html
<li id="listItem">
    This is some text
    <span id="firstSpan">First span text</span>
    <span id="secondSpan">Second span text</span>
</li>
```

Or without creating a temporary array:

```
const { childNodes } = document.getElementById("listItem");
const text = Array.prototype.reduce.call(childNodes, (text, node) =>
    node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ? text + node.nodeValue : text
, "").trim();
```

```js
const { childNodes } = document.getElementById("listItem");
const text = Array.prototype.reduce.call(childNodes, (text, node) =>
    node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ? text + node.nodeValue : text
, "").trim();
console.log(text);
```

```html
<li id="listItem">
    This is some text
    <span id="firstSpan">First span text</span>
    <span id="secondSpan">Second span text</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use the [createTreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) to find all texts elements not attached to html elements (this function can be used to extend jQuery):

```js
function textNodesOnlyUnder(el) {
  var resultSet = [];
  var n = null;
  var treeWalker  = document.createTreeWalker(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, function (node) {
    if (node.parentNode.id == el.id && node.textContent.trim().length != 0) {
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }
    return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
  }, false);
  while (n = treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    resultSet.push(n);
  }
  return resultSet;
}



window.onload = function() {
  var ele = document.getElementById('listItem');
  var textNodesOnly = textNodesOnlyUnder(ele);
  var resultingText = textNodesOnly.map(function(val, index, arr) {
    return 'Text element N. ' + index + ' --> ' + val.textContent.trim();
  }).join('\n');
  document.getElementById('txtArea').value = resultingText;
}
```

```html
<li id="listItem">
    This is some text
    <span id="firstSpan">First span text</span>
    <span id="secondSpan">Second span text</span>
</li>
<textarea id="txtArea" style="width: 400px;height: 200px;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using plain JavaScript in IE 9+ compatible syntax in just a few lines:

```
const childNodes = document.querySelector('#listItem').childNodes;

if (childNodes.length > 0) {
    childNodesLoop:
    for (let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
        //only target text nodes (nodeType of 3)
        if (childNodes[i].nodeType === 3) {
            //do not target any whitespace in the HTML
            if (childNodes[i].nodeValue.trim().length > 0) {
                childNodes[i].nodeValue = 'Replacement text';
                //optimized to break out of the loop once primary text node found
                break childNodesLoop;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of notes: I wouldn't call that variable `children`, because the `children` property of an element is a list of its child *elements*. I'd use `childNodes` to avoid confusion. Also, there's no need for the label, there's just the one loop, `break` will break the right thing. Also, the "primary text" thing seems to come out of left field, the OP doesn't mention stopping early for any reason.

Comment: The variable renaming sounds good, but I used a label for the for loop just because I like to see which loop I'm breaking especially when there's text in between. It doesn't hurt performance to label the for loop. And in the original post, it said "a text node" which makes anyone infer that there is only one element being targeted in that list. It is faster to break if there's only one possibility to replace.

Comment: As you say, no harm in labelling it for clarity. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Get all text in an element without text in any child elements still seems non trivial to do in 2022.
No jQuery needed though.

To get all raw textNode(s) content:

```
const getElementTextWithoutChildElements = (el) =>
  Array.from(el.childNodes)               // iterator to array
    .filter(node => node.nodeType === 3)  // only text nodes
    .map(node => node.textContent)        // get text
    .join('')                             // stick together
;
```

Or similar, using reduce:

```
const getElementTextWithoutChildElements = (el) =>
  [].reduce.call(
    el.childNodes, 
    (a, b) => a + (b.nodeType === 3 ? b.textContent : ''),
    ''
  );
```

---

Should work with this:

```
<div>
  you get this
  <b>not this</b>
  you get this   too
</div>
```

will return:

```
  you get this

  you get this   too
```

---

Whitespace between elements could be tricky, suggest using with .trim() and/or normalize all whitespace, e.g.
For debugging and logging to quickly identify elements I find this is usually enough:

```
getElementTextWithoutChildElements(...).replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
// 'you get this you get this too'
```

Though you might want to tweak whitespace differently, perhaps within the reduce() function itself to handle whitespace per node.

e.g. whitespace handling per node:

```
const getElementTextWithoutChildElements_2 = (el) =>
  Array.from(el.childNodes)
    .filter(node => node.nodeType === 3)
    .map(node => node.textContent.trim()) // added .trim()
    .join(',')                            // added ','
;
```

---

Quick tests for things above:

```
document.body.innerHTML = `
  you get this
  <b>not this</b>
  you get this   too
`;
// '\n  you get this\n  <b>not this</b>\n  you get this   too\n'

getElementTextWithoutChildElements(document.body);
// '\n  you get this\n  \n  you get this   too\n'

getElementTextWithoutChildElements(document.body).replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
// 'you get this you get this too'

getElementTextWithoutChildElements_2(document.body);
// 'you get this,you get this   too'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way for me

```
   var text  =  $('#listItem').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as DotNetWala's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8851526/369450).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a specific solution that should be much more efficient than the cloning and modifying of the clone.  This solution only works with the following two reservations, but should be more efficient than the currently accepted solution:

1. You are getting only the text
2. The text you want to extract is before the child elements

With that said, here is the code:

```
// 'element' is a jQuery element
function getText(element) {
  var text = element.text();
  var childLength = element.children().text().length;
  return text.slice(0, text.length - childLength);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dexterity/8Lud1fy4/8/)

```
<li id="listItem">
    This is some text
    <span id="firstSpan">First span text</span>
    <span id="secondSpan">Second span text</span>
</li>

<input id="input" style="width: 300px; margin-top: 10px;">

    <script type="text/javascript">
$("#input").val($("#listItem").clone().find("span").remove().end().text().trim());
    //use .trim() to remove any white space
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For beginners:

I preferred [@DUzun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32170000/6595520) because it's simple to understand and more efficient than the accepted answer. But it only partially worked for me as you can't directly pass the element with a class selector like this

```
$(".landing-center .articlelanding_detail").get(0).immediateText() //gives .immediateText is not a function error
```

or this

```
$(".landing-center .articlelanding_detail")[0].immediateText() //gives .immediateText is not a function error
```

because once you extract the native Element by using [index] or .get(index) out of the $() function you loose jQuery Object methods chainability as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62119881/jquery-clone-is-not-a-function). And most of the solutions are only in context to ids, not so elegant to use multiple times for the elements with a class selectors.

So, I wrote jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.mainText = function(x=0) {
    return $.trim(this.eq(x).contents().not(this.eq(x).children()).text().replace(/[\t\n]+/g,' '));
};
```

This will return the text of the element irrespective of if ids or class are used as selectors excluding child elements. Also will remove any `\t or \n` to get a clean string.
Use it like this:

**Case 1**

```
$("#example").mainText(); // get the text of element with example id
```

**Case 2**

```
$(".example").mainText(); // get the text of first element with example class
```

**Case 3**

```
$(".example").mainText(1); // get the text of second element with example class and so on..
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative version of the [answere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3442757/16103795) without JQuery

```
[...document.getElementById("listItem").childNodes].find(c => c.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE).nodeValue
```

Answer (score -1):

Just like the question, I was trying to extract text in order to do some regex substitution of the text but was getting problems where my inner elements (ie: `<i>`, `<div>`, `<span>`, etc.) were getting also removed.

The following code seems to work well and solved all my problems.

It uses some of the answers provided here but in particular, will only substitute the text when the element is of `nodeType === 3`.

```
$(el).contents().each(function() { 
  console.log(" > Content: %s [%s]", this, (this.nodeType === 3));

  if (this.nodeType === 3) {
    var text = this.textContent;
    console.log(" > Old   : '%s'", text);

    regex = new RegExp("\\[\\[" + rule + "\\.val\\]\\]", "g");
    text = text.replace(regex, value);

    regex = new RegExp("\\[\\[" + rule + "\\.act\\]\\]", "g");
    text = text.replace(regex, actual);

    console.log(" > New   : '%s'", text);
    this.textContent = text;
  }
});
```

What the above does is loop through all the elements of the given `el` (which was simply obtained with `$("div.my-class[name='some-name']");`. For each inner element, it basically ignores them. For each portion of text (as determined by `if (this.nodeType === 3)`) it will apply the regex substitution only to those elements.

The `this.textContent = text` portion simply replaces the substituted text, which in my case, I was looking for tokens like `[[min.val]]`, `[[max.val]]`, etc.

This short code excerpt will help anyone trying to do what the question was asking ... and a bit more.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how flexible or how many cases you need it to cover, but for your example, if the text always comes before the first HTML tags – why not just split the inner html at the first tag and take the former:

```
$('#listItem').html().split('<span')[0];
```

and if you need it wider maybe just

```
$('#listItem').html().split('<')[0];
```

and if you need the text between two markers, like after one thing but before another, you can do something like (untested) and use if statements to make it flexible enough to have a start or end marker or both, while avoiding null ref errors:

```
var startMarker = '';// put any starting marker here
var endMarker = '<';// put the end marker here
var myText = String( $('#listItem').html() );
// if the start marker is found, take the string after it
myText = myText.split(startMarker)[1];        
// if the end marker is found, take the string before it
myText = myText.split(endMarker)[0];
console.log(myText); // output text between the first occurrence of the markers, assuming both markers exist.  If they don't this will throw an error, so some if statements to check params is probably in order...
```

I generally make utility functions for useful things like this, make them error free, and then rely on them frequently once solid, rather than always rewriting this type of string manipulation and risking null references etc.  That way, you can re-use the function in lots of projects and never have to waste time on it again debugging why a string reference has an undefined reference error.  Might not be the shortest 1 line code ever, but after you have the utility function, it is one line from then on.  Note most of the code is just handling parameters being there or not to avoid errors :)

For example:

```
/**
* Get the text between two string markers.
**/
function textBetween(__string,__startMark,__endMark){
    var hasText = typeof __string !== 'undefined' && __string.length > 0;
    if(!hasText) return __string;
    var myText = String( __string );
    var hasStartMarker = typeof __startMark !== 'undefined' && __startMark.length > 0 && __string.indexOf(__startMark)>=0;
    var hasEndMarker =  typeof __endMark !== 'undefined' && __endMark.length > 0 && __string.indexOf(__endMark) > 0;
    if( hasStartMarker )  myText = myText.split(__startMark)[1];
    if( hasEndMarker )    myText = myText.split(__endMark)[0];
    return myText;
}

// now with 1 line from now on, and no jquery needed really, but to use your example:
var textWithNoHTML = textBetween( $('#listItem').html(), '', '<'); // should return text before first child HTML tag if the text is on page (use document ready etc)
```

Comment: if you need to replace text, just use `$('#listItem').html( newHTML )`; where newHTML is a variable that already has the stripped down text.

Answer (score -2):

Use an extra condition to check if innerHTML and innerText are the same. Only in those cases, replace the text.

```
$(function() {
$('body *').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).html());
    console.log($(this).text());
    if($(this).text() === "Search" && $(this).html()===$(this).text())  {
        $(this).html("Find");
    }
})
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7RSGh/

Answer (score -2):

To be able to trim the result, use DotNetWala's like so:

```
$("#foo")
    .clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text()
    .trim();
```

I found out that using the shorter version like `document.getElementById("listItem").childNodes[0]` won't work with jQuery's trim().

Comment: That's because `document.getElementById("listItem").childNodes[0]` is plain javascript, you'd have to wrap it in the jQuery function `$(document.getElementById("listItem").childNodes[0]).trim()`

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Haha. Thanks!

Comment: This is nearly identical to DotNetWala's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8851526/369450). All you did was added `.trim()` to the end. Is this answer necessary?

Answer (score -3):

just put it in a `<p>` or `<font>` and grab that $('#listItem font').text()

First thing that came to mind

```
<li id="listItem">
    <font>This is some text</font>
    <span id="firstSpan">First span text</span>
    <span id="secondSpan">Second span text</span>
</li>
```

Comment: I don't have control over putting the free text in tags, because the code I'm working off of was not created by me. If I could grab just that text, I could remove it and replace it with tags around it, or do anything I want. But again, the html is already pre-written.

Comment: ah, ok. Then I think you're going to have to filter the results :S

sorry.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this

```
alert(document.getElementById('listItem').firstChild.data)
```

Answer (score -3):

I am not a jquery expert, but how about,

```
$('#listItem').children().first().text()
```

Comment: If you're note a jquery expert, then why not become more of an expert by reading through the other answers first?... One of them happened to be virtually the same as what you wrote, with comments below that explain why it's not a good idea.

Answer (score -4):

This untested, but I think you may be able to try something like this:

```
 $('#listItem').not('span').text();
```

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: Because it's the same as `$('#listItem').text()`. `#listItem` isn't a `<span>` so adding `not('span')` doesn't do anything.