# Clip content with jQuery

Tags: jquery

to just get the number inside span, use the code below:

```
<h3>test <span>inside 123458</span></h3>


alert($('h3 span').text().match(/\d/))
//123458
```

And to just get the content h3, without taking the span of content, how?

Comment: include the markup, it will be easier for people to answer your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution

```
alert( $('h3').clone().find('span').remove().end().text() );
```

pure JS solution

```
alert( document.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].childNodes[0].textContent );
```

examples : http://jsfiddle.net/2mTLg/1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse just the number then try this:

```
<h3>test <span>inside 123458</span></h3>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert($('h3 span').text().match(/\d+/));
</script>
```

Hope this helps. Here is a jsFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/pkMB2/1/

Bob