# How to get text around an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have

```
<div id='wrapper'>
  <fieldset id='fldset'>
    <legend>Title</legend>
    Body text.
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

How could I retrieve the "Body text" without retrieving the text inside of legend tag?

For instance, if I wanted to see if the text inside the fieldset contains the word "body" and change that word, while ignoring whatever might be in the legend? innerHTML retrieves all text from all children nodes.

Use of jQuery wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clip content with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480235/clip-content-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#fldset").contents().eq(2).text();
```

Comment: This gets the content of the legend tag as well... http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/FfSap/

Comment: @subhaze: That's because you're calling #wrapper not #fldset.

Comment: @Ege Özcan: I try to answer question to the context they're were asked in and leave it up to the asker to request further tuning.

Comment: @Babiker, interesting... I copy/pasted that directly from your answer when it was posted...

Comment: @subhaze: You're right, initially that's how i answered, but i edited my answer before you even commented.

Comment: @Babiker, ok thought that was initially how you had it. The way you worded the comment it made it seem as if I had wrote that. Guess my screen didn't update to see your new edit. Glad to see you corrected it!

Answer (score 3):

Without a library --

```
var fldset = document.getElementById("fldset"),
    txt = fldset.lastChild.textContent || fldset.lastChild.innerText;

alert(txt);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will get all the text nodes of `fldset` leaving out any other element and it's content:

```
var fldsetContent = $('#fldset').contents();
var text = '';
$(fldsetContent).each( function(index, item) {
    if( item.nodeType == 3 ) text += $.trim($(item).text());
});
alert( text );
```

**[Live example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/FfSap/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#fldset').clone().find('legend').remove().end().text()
```

But you should also search around the SO

- [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)
- [Clip content with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480235/clip-content-with-jquery/4480266#4480266)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way other than

```
$("#result").html($("#wrapper").text().replace($("legend").text(),""));
```

but there should be a **more elegant way**. You can also create a new element as a copy of this one, remove all the children and get text. Hmm... **That would be**:

```
var newElement = $("#fldset").clone();
newElement.children().remove();
$("#result").html(newElement.text());
```

So doesn't matter how many and which type of children node has, this would work. Here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/wFV4c/

Answer (score 0):

To turn all plain text nodes inside the field set red:

```
jQuery.each($('#fldset').contents(),function(index,value){
  if(value.textContent == value.nodeValue){
    $(this).wrap('<span style="color:red;" />')
  }
});
```