# I need to determine only the innertext of the ul element, without getting the inner content of the li

Tags: javascript, dom

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            document.querySelector("#dropdown");
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="dropdown" tabindex="1">
        test data
        <li><a href="#">Male</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Female</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>**
```

From the above code I need to determine only the innertext of the ul element, without getting the inner content of the li.

If I use the innerText or innetContent, it returns 
"testdata
Male
Female"

however I only need the contents as 
"testdata".

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1 : Cannot use jquery here due to some limitations. Need some logic in terms of Javascript.

Comment: See here for the vanilla Javascript solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4501658

Comment: Thanks guys, I am testing the solution. Will inform in case I face any road blocks.