# jQuery get .text() but not the text in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, textnode

This is my jQuery part that makes my menu for my pages.

```
function fetchmenus() {
    $.getJSON('sys/classes/fetch.php?proccess=1', function(status) {
        // get line status
        $.each(status, function(i, item) {
            if (item.id == "1") {
                active = "class='active'";
                lastpageid = item.href;
            }
            else {
                active = "class='nonactive'";
            }
            $('<li id="' + item.href + '" ' + active + '><a href="#' + item.href + '">' + item.menuTitle + '<span class="menuspan" id="' + item.href + '"></span></a></li>').appendTo('#menuarea ul#mainmenu');

        });
    });
}
```

What I want to do is get the `item.menuTitle` in the `<a` but before the `<span>`.

Currently I do it on this way:

```
$('ul#mainmenu li').live('click', function(event) {
    //alert(this.id);
    $("li#" + lastpageid).removeClass();
    fetchpage(this.id);

    $("#largemenutop").html($(this).text());

    $("li#" + this.id).addClass("active");
    lastpageid = this.id;
});;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: its not clear to me what you are asking. are you looking for a better way to build up the html for the menu? Or to access the title of the anchor once the menu is built already?

Comment: here is a sample
<li id="messages"><a href="#messages">Messages<span class="menuspan" id="bmessages">4</span></a></li>

What is happening it when I click that link it shows the following Messages4 when I want it to show Messages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can select only the text contents of the element, like this:

```
 var text = '';
 $('a').contents().each(function(){
    if(this.nodeType === 3){
     text += this.wholeText;
    }
 });
 $("#largemenutop").html(text);
```

Comment: +1 Herman, good solution.  Here's a [list of NodeTypes](http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/dom-nodetype-constants/) for anyone wondering what '3' means.

Comment: I fixed it by using some of the code above.

Now it looks like this and works, maybe not the cleanest.

[code]
$('ul#mainmenu li').live('click', function(event){
   //alert(this.id);
   
   $("li#"+lastpageid).removeClass();
   fetchpage(this.id);
   
   
   var text = '';
    $('li#'+this.id+' a').contents().each(function(){
      if(this.nodeType === 3){
       text += this.wholeText;
      }
    });
   
   $("#largemenutop").html(text);
   
   $("li#"+this.id).addClass("active");
   lastpageid = this.id;
 });
[/code]

Answer (score 23):

Nice solution Herman, though it can be reduced to something like this:

### JS

```
$('li a').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();
```

### HTML

```
<li><a href="#">Apple<span>hi</span> Juice</a></li>
```

Will return `Apple Juice`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/49sHa/1/

Comment: +1: This cleaner version made it easier for me to understand the solution