# jQuery - get only parent element text without children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page I'm scraping, and the text I'm looking for is inside a `span` that contains another `span`

```
<div class="someParentDiv">
  <span>this is the text I want   
    <span class="childSpanClass">I don't want this text</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the text I want with a jQuery selection, but when I get the elemnt's text with `text()`, I will get also the child span's text, which I don't want.

I managed to get only the text I want with

```
$('div.someParentDiv span').remove('.childSpanClass')
```

but it seems a little backwards to me ([see example](http://jsfiddle.net/sz34ar7o/1/)), and I'm wondering if there's a better, nicer way to do it.
Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery exclude some child nodes from .text()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270607/jquery-exclude-some-child-nodes-from-text)

Comment: @Mritunjay - it's similar, but not exactly the same situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter away everything that is **not** plain text by looping all `contents`:

```
var node = $('.someParentDiv > span').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3; // text node
});

alert(node.text());
```

Comment: Nice. I was not aware of the whole `nodeType` thing.

Answer (score 1):

Without JQuery: pick the `textContent` of the first child of the `span` element in `div.someParentDiv`. The first child is the `TEXT_NODE` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType)) of that span, which is a (non visible) separate node. With JQuery use `$('.someParentDiv span').contents().first('[nodeType=3]').text();`

```js
var res = document.querySelector('#result');

// no jquery
res.innerHTML = 'DOM: ' + 
                 document.querySelector('.someParentDiv span').firstChild.textContent;

// jquery

res.innerHTML += '<br>JQuery: ' +  
                 $('.someParentDiv span').contents().first('[nodeType=3]').text();
```

```css
#result {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someParentDiv">
  <span>this is the text I want   
    <span class="childSpanClass">I don't want this text</span>
  </span>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem:

[jQuery get .text() but not the text in span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913031/jquery-get-text-but-not-the-text-in-span)

NodeType explained

http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/dom-nodetype-constants/