# Selecting <li> value which contains the hidden <span> value

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div id="left">
    <ul class="cmdSelected">
        <li class="cmdTitle">Test Case D</li>
            <li class="cmdTypeE">GPP1<span hidden>143</span></li>
            <li class="cmdTypeE">GPP2<span hidden>146</span></li>               
            <li class="cmdTypeF">UDA<span hidden>0</span></li>
            <li class="cmdTypeB">Complete<span hidden>1</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to show the value "GPP1" when I click it.

```
$( "li.cmdTypeE" ).on("click", function() {
    var selected = $(this).text();   //Can't work properly
});
```

However, it will show the value "GPP1143".
What can I do to fetch the value "GPP1" only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Comment: [`this.childNodes[0].nodeValue`](http://jsfiddle.net/tkvfk65L/)

Comment: @billyonecan pinned it. You can answer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:-

```
 var selected = $(this).text();
```

With:-

```
var selected = $("#left >ul").find("li:selected").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

or

```
var selected = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

> .clone()    -- clone the element.
>       .children()  -- select all the children.
>       .remove()    -- remove all the children.
>       .end()       -- again go back to selected element.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<div id="left">
    <ul class="cmdSelected">
        <li class="cmdTitle">Test Case D</li>
            <li class="cmdTypeE">GPP1<span hidden>143</span></li>
            <li class="cmdTypeE">GPP2<span hidden>146</span></li>               
            <li class="cmdTypeF">UDA<span hidden>0</span></li>
            <li class="cmdTypeB">Complete<span hidden>1</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "li.cmdTypeE" ).on("click", function() {
    var selected = $(this).contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; }).text();
    console.log(selected);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxs210La/

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915443/814110

Answer (score -2):

Try This:

```
<div id="left">
<ul class="cmdSelected">
    <li class="cmdTitle">Test Case D</li>
        <li class="cmdTypeE" onclick="clickonthis(this)">GPP1<span hidden>143</span></li>
        <li class="cmdTypeE" onclick="clickonthis(this)">GPP2<span hidden>146</span></li>               
        <li class="cmdTypeF" onclick="clickonthis(this)">UDA<span hidden>0</span></li>
        <li class="cmdTypeB" onclick="clickonthis(this)">Complete<span hidden>1</span></li>
</ul>
```

on script:

```
function clickonthis(obj) {
    var selected = $(obj).text();
    alert(selected);  
}
```

Comment: OMG, repetitive online javascript, that's certainly not the way to go. Besides, it doesn't change anything, this doesn't work. It outputs "GPP1143" : http://jsfiddle.net/d43utya4/1/