# How to get the text of parent element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, text, parent

I have a div which contains a delete hyperlink, onlick of it, I want the text of the div tag. How is it possible in jquery?!

```
<div>sometext<a href="#">delete</a></div>
```

I want to get the text of div tag 'sometext' and if possible the id of that div too.
Any ideas?!

Comment: Are you wanting to just get `sometext` because the normal `.text()` method everyone is suggesting will **NOT** get just `sometext` it will actually return `sometext delete` becasue the `<a/>` is within the `<div/>`

Comment: yes, I want to just get the sometext!

Comment: Really so good to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem with doing:

```
$(this).parent().text();
```

is that it will get ALL the text within the div (sometext AND delete).

I'm assuming you only want the text in the div and not the link.

I've knocked up an example on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HK794/

Ideally you might want to wrap the text in a span, like:

```
<div id="div1"><span>sometext</span><a href="#">delete</a></div>
```

Then your JavaScript would be:

```
$("a").click(function(e){

    $div = $(this).parent("div");

    id = $div.attr("id");

    text = $div.find("span").text();

    alert( text  );

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**EDIT**

As @DarthJDG states if you don't want to change your markup, any these would also work:

```
text = $div.get(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;

//OR    
text = $div[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

//OR
text = $div.get(0).firstChild.nodeValue;

//OR
text = $div[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

//OR

//Gets the first text node
$div.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).text();
```

Comment: Just in case you wouldn't want to change your HTML markup, you could extract the first text node from the HTML DOM: `$(this).parent()[0].firstChild.nodeValue`

Comment: @tfbox Yes your right but it would be easier to change the HTML markup than write some JavaScript which just seems hacky.

Comment: Good point @DarthJDG, added it into answer. Forgot about using that.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var content;
        $(this).parent().contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3;
        }).each(
                function(i,el){
                    content = content + $(el).text();
                }
        );
```

This sets content to the value of any direct children which are text.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
    var html = $(this).parent('div').html().replace(/<.*>/g, "");
    alert(html);
});
```

Comment: it should strip all html now.

Comment: I am afraid it still giving the same value!

Answer (score 0):

Although adding in a span tag would probably more efficent

http://jsfiddle.net/tN8Mv/

```
$("a").click(function(){
var text = $(this).parent().clone()    //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove()   //remove all the children
        .end()  //again go back to selected element
        .text();
    alert(text);
});
```

Comment: @ nickf yep thats why I added the text above my answer :) was jsut giving him all options

Answer (score 0):

```
mySiblingtext="";
myParentId = "";
    $('a').click(function(){
        var mypart = $(this)[0].previousSibling;
        mySiblingtext= $(mypart).text();
        myParentId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        alert(mySiblingText+myParentId);
    });
```

jQuery skips over text nodes for all of its traversal methods ( except .contents() ). To access the previous sibling, then text in this case, regardless of nodeType, you can access the DOM node and then use the .previousSibling property. Then you can access the text of that element.

Access to the Id if the parent is then simple as well.

Sample fiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/FuQ6g/

NOTE: one advantage of this method is if you have markup like:

```
<div id='aparent'>sometext<a href="#">delete</a>stuff after</div>
```

the "stuff after" text is not selected.

Answer (score -1):

jQueryElement.parent().text();