# Jquery select text after a div without id or class

Tags: jquery

Here is my html code:

```
<div>
    Please complete this form to create a new account.
    <br>
    Fields marked  with (*) are required.
    <div id="errorZone"></div>
</div>
```

I want to select text between div and div id="errorZone".

I'm trying this code:

```
$('#errorZone').prev().text().remove();
```

But this doesn't work

Comment: try this : `$('#errorZone').parent().remove('br').text();`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove everything (including the `<br />`):

```
var start = document.getElementById('errorZone');
while (start.previousSibling) {
    start.parentNode.removeChild(start.previousSibling);
}
```

```js
var start = document.getElementById('errorZone');
while (start.previousSibling) {
  start.parentNode.removeChild(start.previousSibling);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Please complete this form to create a new account.
  <br>Fields marked with (*) are required.
  <div id="errorZone">Text in 'errorZone.'</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This what I'm looking for.I want to remove text including br.Thank you.I appreciated your help.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#errorZone').closest('div:not('.errorZone')').remove();
```

Comment: Try this one. may be this will help you. in mean while i am trying to find out a better option for you.

Comment: You are a great team :)

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use the .parent() instead of .prev(). See this link:-
[How to get the text of parent element using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138989/how-to-get-the-text-of-parent-element-using-jquery)