# Get the text after span element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this html code

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <div>
        <span>Text inside span</span>
        Text next to span
    </div>
    <div>
        Contents inside the 2nd div element...
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to get the **"Text next to span"**. I tried this code JQuery code

```
var a = $('#mydiv div').first().find('span').parent().text();
alert(a);
```

The output of the jquery code above is this:

```
Text inside span
Text next to span
```

What should be the right thing to do to just get only the **"Text next to span"**?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

Comment: The post is to advanced for me to understand. I'm sorry.

Comment: It is the same question you asked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```js
var a = $('#mydiv div').first().contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
  <div>
    <span>Text inside span</span> 
    Text next to span
  </div>
  <div>
    Contents inside the 2nd div element...
  </div>
</div>
```

This gets the contents of the selected `div`, and filters the matched set, returning only elements with `nodeType == 3`, which are text nodes.

Answer (score 13):

I got it by this:

```
$('#mydiv div').first().contents().eq(1).text();
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this code:

```
 $('#myDiv')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
  }).text();
```

Comment: It's better to use `nodeType == 3` rather than the `TEXT_NODE` constant, which is not supported by IE.

Comment: @James thanks, I was unknown about the integer value of nodeType

Answer (score 0):

Use `Node.nextSibling`

```js
let jqElt_SearchRegion = $('#mydiv div').first();
let jqElt_SearchPoint = jqElt_SearchRegion.find('span');

let node_Sibling = jqElt_SearchPoint[0].nextSibling; // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling
console.log(node_Sibling.textContent); // Text next to span.
```

---

<sub><sup>*(if jQuery is not a strict requirement)*</sup></sub>