# How to select strings next to the elements?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the text after span element using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925088/get-the-text-after-span-element-using-jquery)

I am trying to select the text next to a span element.

I have

```
    <span class='spanClass'>span text</span>

test this string....
```

I used

```
$('.spanClass').next().val() ->give me undefined....

//how to get the 'test this string....'?
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925088/get-the-text-after-span-element-using-jquery out

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
<div>
    <span class='spanClass'>span text</span> 
    <label>Hello World!!</label>
</div>

   $('.spanClass').next().text();

            OR

   $('.spanClass').next().html();
```

.val() is used for input elements.. 
.text() is for labels and divs

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** bit different `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/4Rx2r/

Also you can chuck that in your js file as a plugin `:)` if you want.

Hope it fits the need `:)`

**Code**

```
jQuery.fn.justtext = function() {

    return $(this).clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();

};


alert($('.spanClass').parent().justtext());
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the content of the parent element and filter for textnodes:

```
var text = $('.spanClass').parent().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType===3;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7bzah/1/);