# How to get text node after element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, textnode

Using jQuery.
I have the following html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name='something' value='v1' /> All the world <br />
```

How would I get ONLY the text. what selector should I use?
(I need the "All the world")

I also can not touch the HTML...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925088/get-the-text-after-span-element-using-jquery

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try using the DOM function  `.nextSibling` to pick the next node (including the text nodes) and use `nodeValue` to get the text `All the world`

```
$(':checkbox')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue
```

Comment: You can also remove text by editing this property.

Answer (score 9):

Just use the plain-JavaScript `nextSibling`, though you have to 'drop out of' jQuery to use that method (hence the `[0]`):

```
var text = $('input:checkbox[name="something"]')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rbDN8/1/).

And I finally realised what was wrong with my other suggestion, which has been fixed:

```
var text = $('input:checkbox[name="something"]').parent().contents().filter(
    function(){
        return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() !== '';
    }).first().text();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rbDN8/3/).

And to make sure that you're only getting the `textNodes` from *before* the `br` (though frankly this is becoming overly-complex, and the first suggestion works far more easily and, I suspect reliably):

```
var text = $('input:checkbox[name="something"]').parent().contents().filter(
    function(){
        return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() !== '' && $(this).prevAll('br').length === 0;
    }).text();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rbDN8/4/).

Comment: If you are going to use `filter` you can very well use `.text()` on text nodes.. no need `[0].nodeValue`.. just that jQuery doesn't have a way to select the text node.

Comment: This does not yield the text.

Comment: Even though OP is asking for the node, it seems that the text is actually wanted. Just add `.data` or `.nodeValue` to the end.

Comment: @KevinBoucher: it certainly *seems* to, in Chromium 18/Ubuntu 11.04. What are you testing in? No, you're right. Edited to correct!

Comment: @KevinBoucher `nextSibling` is to get the node.. to get the text you need to do `nodeValue`

Comment: @David, in the fiddle I changed the `console.log` to `alert` and got '[Object text]'

Comment: Yeah; I realised...hence the addition of `.nodeValue` and an updated demo. =)

Answer (score 3):

If you added a `label` to your markup (which is recommended), you could do it this way:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="something" name="something" value="v1" /><label for="something">All the world</label> <br />
```

JS

```
var text = $( '#something ~ label:first' ).text();
```

Comment: +1 assuming this is the label *(very likely)*, but I'd use a valid Selectors API selector instead so that `querySelectorAll` can be utilized. `$('#something + label')`

Comment: What's wrong with the next siblings selector? http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/

Comment: Nothing at all, but the `:first` is a proprietary Sizzle selector, so it defaults to Sizzle's JavaScript based selector engine instead of the browser's native one.

Comment: @KevinBoucher Right, but the point is it isn't a CSS selector, therefore querySelectorAll can't be utilized, meaning the string then has to be parsed.

Comment: It's a Sizzle selector, and Sizzle is included in jQuery. Either way, you're forfeiting a standards compliant selector that gives you the benefit of being utilized by native code. ...like @KevinB said, but it's more than just the string parsing. The entire DOM selection is done in JavaScript instead of using much faster native code.

Comment: Can't use label, I can't touch the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Just to toss in a example to a way old question, wrap text in a label

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .each(function(index, el) {
    var textNode = $(el.nextSibling);
    if (textNode[0].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      let checkwrap = $(el).wrap('<label class="found"></label>').closest('.found');
      textNode.appendTo(checkwrap);
    }
  });
```

```css
.found {
  border: solid cyan 1px;
  color: blue;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.3em;
}

label.found {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>in a span</span>
<input type="checkbox" name='something' value='v1' /> All the world <br />
<input type="checkbox" name='something2' value='v2' /> All the world 2 <span>in a span</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name='something3' value='v3' /> All the world 3 <span>in a span</span>
<input type="checkbox" name='something4' value='v4' /> All the world 4<span>in a span also</span>
```

there, wrapped in a label, oh wait, that is an answer, just have to get the `nextSibling` isolated by type