# Get particular text node after an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to grab a particular string, " (TEXT 1)", " (TEXT 2)", etc. I cannot change the HTML.

When I do this:

```
$(this).parent().html(); // $(this) is equivalent to $('a.more').
```

I get:

```
<a class="more" href="/e1">Event 1</a> (TEXT 1)<br>
<a class="more" href="/e2">Event 2</a> (TEXT 2)<br>
<a class="more" href="/e3">Event 3</a> (TEXT 3)<br>
```

I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017894/how-to-get-text-node-after-element) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925088/get-the-text-after-span-element-using-jquery).

I can't seem to get a particular "(TEXT n)". Ideally I'd like to get a particular "(TEXT n)". Something along the lines of:

```
$('a.more').nextText(1); // this would return " (TEXT 2)"
```

How can I get a particular string with either JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Maybe you could just wrap the (TEXT n) in <span>...</span> and search for the spans...

Comment: The html is not mine and I can't change it. If it were my html, it would be very easy for me to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your post implies, if you want to create a custom `.nextText()` method, just access the [`nodeValue` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) of the DOM element's next sibling:

```
$.fn.nextText = function() {
  return this.length ? this[0].nextSibling.nodeValue : null;
};
```

Then you can use the `.eq()` method to get the element by its index and use the custom method:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrkyn40n/)

```
var text = $('.more').eq(0).nextText();
console.log(text); // (TEXT 1)
```

---

If you want to add a parameter to pass the index of the element you want to retrieve the text from:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/dveyowo5/)

```
$.fn.nextText = function(index) {
  return this.length ? this[index || 0].nextSibling.nodeValue : null;
};

var text = $('.more').nextText(1);
console.log(text); // (TEXT 2)
```

---

If you want to get multiple elements and text nodes until a specific element (as the OP did in the comments), you can use this custom `.nextTextUntil()` method:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/24frpo55/)

```
$.fn.nextTextUntil = function(until) {
  var text = '', next;

  if (this.length) {
    next = this[0].nextSibling;

    while (next !== null && until && !$(next).is(until)) {
      text += next.nodeValue || next.textContent;
      next = next.nextSibling;
    }
  }

  return text;
};
```

Usage:

```
$('.more').eq(0).nextTextUntil('.more');
```

Would return:

```
(TEXT 1 MORE TEXT)
```

Based on the following HTML:

```
<a class="more" href="/e1">Event 1</a> (TEXT 1 <em>MORE TEXT</em>)
```

Comment: I'm having an issue. When the html looks like this: <a class="more" href="/e1">Event 1</a> (TEXT 1 <em>MORE TEXT</em> ASDF) - helloworld <br> I'm only getting " (TEXT 1". How can I get the full " (TEXT 1 MORE TEXT ASDF) - helloworld "?

Comment: @rotaercz How do you know when to stop retrieving text? Do you want to get all elements and text nodes *until* the next `.more` element?

Comment: Basically I'd like to retrieve everything at the same sibling level (and children) as  "(TEXT 1)". Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'd like to get all elements and text nodes until the next .more element but at the sibling and children level (no parents).

Comment: @rotaercz Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/wn95Lksb/ I created a `.nextTextUntil()` method.

Comment: That worked perfectly. If I could upvote your answer again I would. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `nextSibling` method of the underlying DOMElement to get the sibling textNode. Try this:

```
console.log($('.more')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue)); // = '(TEXT 1)'
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rtkk0jLz/)

Note that to get the textNode next to the other `.more` elements, you can change the index to `1` or `2`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work, or am I misunderstandig your exact question?

https://jsfiddle.net/xhp86ygq/

`document.querySelector('.more').nextSibling.nodeValue`

Now if you need a function that does this for a given node:

```
getNextTextnodeValue = function(element) {
    return element.nextSibling.nodeValue;
};
```

Really writing this into a jQuery plugin would just add lots of bulk to the code, and you'd gain nothing as it's not chainable (returns a string, not a jQuery object).

Answer (score 1):

My proposal, not efficent, but all in jQuery consists in finding a small area where you can reduce the search:

```js
$.fn.getTextNodes = function(contentText) {
  return $(this).find(":not(iframe)").addBack().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf(contentText) != -1;
  });
};

$(function () {
  var result = $('#areaWhereToSearch').getTextNodes('(TEXT 1)');
  if (result.length == 1) {
    $('#result').text($('#areaWhereToSearch').getTextNodes('(TEXT 1)')[0].nodeValue);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<div id="areaWhereToSearch">
    <a class="more" href="/e1">Event 1</a> (TEXT 1)<br>
    <a class="more" href="/e2">Event 2</a> (TEXT 2)<br>
    <a class="more" href="/e3">Event 3</a> (TEXT 3)<br>
</div>
<p id="result"></p>
```