# What is the correct way to deal with texts outside the tag?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

What is the correct way to deal with texts outside the tags

I tried all the methods, but all failed

And I experimented with this

```
 <script>

  $(function(){
  var A = $(".A").text();
  var B = $(".B").text();
  var C = $(".C").text();
  var D = $(".D").text();
  $("#BD").text(A+B+C+D);
      });

  </script>

  <body>

   <div>
    <span class="A"></span>6
    <span class="B"></span>8
    <span class="C"></span>3
    <span class="D"></span>9
  </div>

  <div id="BD"></div>
  </body>
```

As well as this

```
<script>

$(function(){
 var A = $(".A").text();
 var B = $(".B").text();
 var C = $(".C").text();
 var D = $(".D").text();
  alert(A+B+C+D);
});

 </script>
```

But they all didn't work

How can I collect the numbers correctly?!

Comment: Is there a reason the text is not in the tag? The HTML structure here seems very unusual.

Comment: Your function $(".A").text() gets only text which is inside element with id 'A'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could clone the div and remove the span elements inside so then retrieve the div text with `.text()`, just do:

```
$('#BD').text( $('.A').parent().clone().children('span').remove().end().text() );
```

See working [**demo**](https://tinker.io/0b1b8)

Comment: This solution perhaps is better, and shorter, if you need everything anyways. Not if they are needed separately.

Comment: Thank you

But I want only one

<span class="B"> </ span> 8

How??

Comment: @khaled sorry I didn't understand your question, can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/dS3ab/2/

As borrowed from [James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925088/get-the-text-after-span-element-using-jquery#answer-6925135)

```
var a = $("div").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();

$("#BD").text(a);​
```

Note that this solution only works to get all textNodes inside the div-tag!

Comment: This is wrong. `next` selects the sibling elements, not textNodes, if you see your fiddle `#BD` contains nothing.

Comment: @undefined You are right, I was wrong.