# Get text in parent without children using cheerio

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to extract just the content of a div - without any of the children of that div - using cheerio.  If I just use div.text() - I get all the text - parent and children.  Here's the HTML - I just want the value "5.25"

The code below currently returns "Purchase price $5.25"

The HTML below:

```
<div class="outer tile"> 
    < ... various other html here > 
    <div class="cost">
        <span class="text">Purchase price </span>
        <small>$</small>5.25
    </div>
</div>
```

with the extract of the relevant node.js CHEERIO code below:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(data);
$("div.outer.tile").each(function(i, e) {
  var price = $(e).find('div.price');
      console.log(price.text());
});
```

Answer (score 24):

Anyone still wondering how to do this in Cheerio:

```
$('div.classname').first().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.type === 'text';
}).text();
```

Answer (score 7):

i like this most:

```
$('div.cost').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

which i find more concise (no idea about efficiency). This will clone the element, and then extract the text from it. Removing children in the clone doesn't affect the original element.

[source](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/)

[runkit](https://runkit.com/fffact/59293292f48c2a00125cc277)

Comment: note that this answer, unlike the top rated one, modifies the underlying cheerio object and will delete the contents of the div

Comment: @Luke Tan this is not the case anymore, in that the original answer has been edited to prevent deleting the contents of the div – or at least that's my understanding

Answer (score 0):

I used this post

[Get the text after span element using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925088/get-the-text-after-span-element-using-jquery)

as reference to make a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/TKwhY/

It was new to me, but you can get text nodes by returning only elements of nodeType 3

```
var a = $('.cost').first().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure it's the last text child, you can use:

```js
$(".cost").contents().last().text().trim();
```

But here's a more general approach than the [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23956052/6243352) (I avoid using `.first()` and trim the text):

```js
import cheerio from "cheerio";

const html = `
<div class="outer tile">
  <div class="cost">
    <span class="text">Purchase price </span>
    <small>$</small>5.25
  </div>
</div>
`;
const $ = cheerio.load(html);

const result = [...$(".cost").contents()]
  .filter(e => e.type === "text" && $(e).text().trim())
  .map(e => $(e).text().trim())
  .join(""); // optional
console.log(result);
```

See also:

- [How to get a text that's separated by different HTML tags in Cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73690939/how-to-get-a-text-thats-separated-by-different-html-tags-in-cheerio/73692854#73692854)
- [cheerio: Get normal + text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878673/cheerio-get-normal-text-nodes/73693773#73693773)
- [How do I get text after single `<br>` tag in Cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74418220/how-do-i-get-text-after-single-br-tag-in-cheerio/74418510#74418510)