# Remove everything between two known characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having the hardest time finding a way to match and remove the text I've been asked to remove.

I can't just match the exact string because it's different every time, but it's always between the same known chars.

```
    <h1 class="art-PostHeader" style="border-bottom:solid 1px; border-bottom-color:#4D909D;"><a href="/content/library-closed-14" title="Library Closed">Building Closed</a></h1>
   Code to Remove <form action=
```

So, while the "Content to be removed" can be anything alpha or numeric, it will always be between `</h1>` and `<form`

There should be a way to write a jQuery `remove()` or `replace()` function to match it, but I can't figure it out. I've tried regular expressions but I'm not the best at those.

Comment: I was able to solve using regexr.com!!! h1>|(.*?)\<form works

Comment: Im not sure how to handle the question now that I dont need an answer? I want to do the correct thing for the community, any help?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6925088/1947286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the nachor tag and get the Next sibling and set the node's value to nothing.

```js
$("h1.art-PostHeader")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = ""
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="art-PostHeader" style="border-bottom:solid 1px; border-bottom-color:#4D909D;"><a href="/content/library-closed-14" title="Library Closed">Building Closed</a></h1> CONTENT TO BE REMOVED<form action="get"></form>
```

Comment: Just FYI the `a` appears to be inside a `h1` tag (although the code is incomplete) so the content to be removed wouldn't be a sibling of the `a` element.

Comment: Correct, I could not get this code to work.. Im updating the question with the full html.

Comment: $("#calpopup-body h1")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "" - This worked!