# Jquery selector to do text() but without class or id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<h1>
    <br>
    USA
    <br>
    <br>
    <p style="margin-top:13px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    Canada 
</h1>
```

Without changing the HTML above, how can I get the value of `Canada` with jQuery selector?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the text after span element using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925088/get-the-text-after-span-element-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the last text-node value, then try this

```js
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
var childNodes = h1.childNodes;
console.log(childNodes[childNodes.length -1 ].nodeValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><br>USA<br><br><p style="margin-top:13px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></p><br><br>Canada </h1>
```

Equivalent jquery would be

```
var h1 = $("h1")[0];
```

Comment: hey the jquery version return the h1 selctor not the value.

Comment: @AlienXu yes, you need to add next two lines to it. I just demonstrated that getting `h1` with javasript and jquery, you still need to iterate their childNodes. Basically, jquery doesn't help you much with textnodes.

Answer (score 1):

If the markup style is consistent -- not prone to change, you can use `xpath`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this:

```
var value = $('h1').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
})[1];
```

Here i use `nodeType == 3`, which selects text nodes.

https://jsfiddle.net/54tw4nw0/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var afterP;

var text = $('h1').contents().filter(function() {
    if (this.nodeName == "P") {
        afterP = true
    }

    return afterP && this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();

console.log(text);
```

Solution copied & enhanced from [Get the text after span element using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925088/get-the-text-after-span-element-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var text = $("h1").html();
alert(text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("<br>") +4));
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/5a1jxtwm/)