# Get text, which goes after span element, not including the text that is before the span, using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code :

```
<div>
    <span>
        First text
        <span class="dot"></span>
        Second text
    </span>
    <span class="other-span">
    </span>
</div>
```

I need to get only **Second text**. I tried this JQuery code:

```
const a = $('div').find('span:nth-child(1)').text();
console.log(a);
```

The output of the jquery code above is this:

```
First text  Second text
```

What should be the right thing to do to get only **Second text** after the **span** element with class **dot**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the text after span element using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925088/get-the-text-after-span-element-using-jquery)

Comment: Place `second text` inside the span tag and then try

Comment: @Xzandro nope, that is slightly different, the solution for the mentioned question is just check for type text, but here if I use that, it returns me both **First text** and **Second text**

Comment: @vinaykumarreddy I can't modify `html` code

Comment: `const a = $('div span').contents().eq(2).text();` Well, it's a bit different, yes, but the idea behind it is basically the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the HTML then strips the text like :

```js
const a = $('div').find('span:nth-child(1)').html().split('<span class="dot"></span>')[1];
console.log(a.trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>
        First text
        <span class="dot"></span> Second text
  </span>
  <span class="other-span">
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nodeType](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp) property. I hope below example will help,

```js
const a = $('div').find('span:nth-child(1)').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
})[1]
console.log(a.textContent.trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>
        First text
        <span class="dot"></span> Second text
  </span>
  <span class="other-span">
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, but for some reasons .textContent returns undefined for me :(

Comment: @DashaRee ok fine. Have you checked above snippet? that's working fine?