# How to get only direct text without tags with jQuery in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I've got an HTML:

```
<strong>1)</strong>TEXT THAT I ONLY NEED<p>some par</p><ul>..</ul>
```

I need only **"TEXT THAT I ONLY NEED"** that is not withing any tags in his HTML, how can I get it with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 60):

The best way is to [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) your object, [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) all of its [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/), then go back to the object using [`.end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/) and finally get the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

The method is described in [this blog post](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/).

```
$("strong")
        .clone()    //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove()   //remove all the children
        .end()  //again go back to selected element
        .text();    //get the text of element
```

Comment: hi @Deglan, How to replace the selected text ?

Comment: Sorry @jafarpinjar, I don't know. You better should open a new question.

Comment: yes here is new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164233/replace-li-end-text-using-jquery

Answer (score 5):

well, if you use jQuery, you would do

```
$('.selector').text();
```

[more info and examples here](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

edit: I just saw you want the text that is not in any tags - well this is not directly possible (fact is, that every text inside a html document is inside some HTML tags.)

In this case I would try to change the markup (easiest way), so the desired text is within html tags.
If this is not possible, you use the above mentioned `text()` method to get the whole text from the parent element, and after you have to subtract the pieces you dont want.

see http://jsfiddle.net/3SSAR/1/ for an example of how to subtract the strings..

just remember to use `substr` and not `-` to subtract strings in javascript

Comment: It will return all the text combined in all nested tags

Comment: This also includes new line and carriage return tags. (\n\r)

Answer (score 4):

This is tricky, because the text is in a text node, and jQuery doesn't support text nodes, only elements. Also because different browsers treat white space in HTML code differently, so you end up with different sets of nodes in different browsers. You can't just get the nodes and rely on that the text node that you want is at the same index all the time.

You can use jQuery to locate an element, and use the DOM to get all the nodes inside it.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="test">
  <strong>1)</strong>
  TEXT THAT I ONLY NEED
  <p>some par</p>
  <ul>
    <li>asdf</li>
    <li>qwerty</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Use jQuery to find the div, use `[0]` to get the DOM element out of the jQuery object, and the `childNodes` property to get its children:

```
var nodes = $('#test')[0].childNodes;
```

Then you can use jQuery to loop through the nodes to find the node that is the `strong` element:

```
var index;
$.each(nodes, function(i,e){
  if (e.tagName == 'STRONG') {
    index = i;
    return false;
  }
});
```

Now you can use the DOM to get the text value from the next node:

```
var text = nodes[index + 1].nodeValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, that cod: .clone().children("strong,p,ul").remove().end().text() did what I need

Comment: @WHITECOLOR: That code will concatenate all text nodes in the element, so it relies on that you don't have any more text, or any line breaks between child elements.

Comment: Great explanation about the inner workings, deserves moar upvotes :) FWIW, I voted again to close as duplicate, the other Q has more exposure and answers covering more ground. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
var el = $("<div/>");
el.html(text).children().remove();
return el.text();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = $($(YourElementOuterHTML)).children().remove().end().text();
```

example:-

```
var name = $($(li).find("a").get(0).outerHTML).children().remove().end().text();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var element = $('#element');
var tags = element.find('*');
tags.remove();
var plainText = element.text().trim();
alert(plainText); // prints TEXT THAT I ONLY NEED
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- html -->
<div id='element'>
  <strong>1)</strong>TEXT THAT I ONLY NEED
  <p>some par</p>
  <ul>..</ul>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2b5dh4xc/

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach With `vanila/pure` JavaScript

```js
const el = document.getElementById('element');
const elNodes = el.childNodes;
let plainText = "";
for(i=0;i<elNodes.length;i++){
   if(elNodes[i].nodeName == '#text'){
     plainText+=elNodes[i].textContent;
   }
}
console.log(plainText); // prints TEXT THAT I ONLY NEED
```

```html
<!-- html -->
<div id='element'>
  <strong>1)</strong>TEXT THAT I ONLY NEED
  <p>some par</p>
  <ul>..</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Your markup isn't the greatest for this. If you wrapped the text you want with a span such as:

```
<span class="gettext">TEXT THAT I NEED</span>
```

You could use `$('.gettext').text();` in jQuery.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't realised that I you couldn't change it. In which case I'd suggest something like frank blizzard's edited answer above