# why when I add `span` tag the text is displayed properly

Tags: html, css

I've got a page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"><head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="sign_in">
             <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="form_submit">
                        <input id="submit_sign_in" class="btn-submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" tabindex="4" type="submit">
                        or
                        <a class="corporate_login" id="corporate_login" href="">
                            Login with corporate domain
                        </a>.
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my `css` file looks like this

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:arial;
}

input#submit_sign_in{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 15px 0 15px;
    height:25px;
    line-height:25px;
    font-size:11px;
    background: url('file.png') top left repeat-x;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

a.corporate_login {
    color:#1568bd;
    text-decoration:none;
}

form#sign_in td.form_submit {
    padding:50px 0 0 0;
    height:85px;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

When I run it in mozilla firefox it's displayed properly.

[image]

But in Opera and Chrome it is not

[image]

I even tried to put this code into jsfiddle - it's displayed there properly too.

To solve the problem I wrapped `or` in `<span></span>` tags. It helped. 
But why this solution works? And what did cause original problem?

Comment: Checked on line-height and vertical-align of both the span and the parent element (td in your case) with Firebug/Dev Tools? That's what I would check on first. Though table rendering is always spooky.

Comment: @user1432980 Your chrome and opera browser version plz?

Comment: @user1432980 check this link you will get some idea about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624592/jquery-how-to-get-only-direct-text-without-tags-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually when you write **or** without span tag. It is treated as a direct member of td tag, as you haven't closed it in with any p or h1,h2,h3 tag. Now being the member of td tag, it will follow all the vertical-align and text-align rules that you have specified.

Chrome is treating it differently because they have their own default submit button size. Not just span tag, you can also enclose it in `<p>` tag too to solve the problem. But you will have to give

tag `display:inline;` property.

Here you can see the result.
http://jsfiddle.net/4ktmqfsc/4/

The red box is showing the boundaries of td tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use vertical-align middle on `a.corporate_login` and `input#submit_sign_in`

```
a.corporate_login,input#submit_sign_in{vertical-align: middle;}
```