# jQuery - How to get text from div > p

Tags: jquery, html

How to get the subject name from within a div class?

```
<div class="subject "><img src="image/eng.jpg"/><p>English</p></div>
<div class="subject "><img src="image/bio.jpg"/><p>Biology</p></div>
<div class="subject "><img src="image/math.jpg"/><p>Mathematic</p></div>
<div class="subject "><img src="image/sci.jpg"/><p>Science</p></div>
```

So, expected result: You select English subject / You select Science subject

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".subject ").click(function(){
         // the script will declare here.
         alert('You are select'+subject+'subject ');
});
```

Comment: You can find the text in `p` by doing `$(this).find('p').text();` inside your click function

Comment: The question would be better titled by something like: *Get CSS class name from parent node*

Comment: @PedroEstrada Go ahead and post an answer

Comment: @Jack no, don't; this is a duplicate and shouldn't be answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: How to get only direct text without tags (in HTML)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624592/jquery-how-to-get-only-direct-text-without-tags-in-html)

Comment: Yeah just close this question, jquery selectors are your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".subject ").click(function() {
  // the script will declare here.
  alert('You are select ' + $(this).find('p').text() + ' subject ');
});
```

```css
div {
  border:1px solid #999;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subject ">
  <img src="image/eng.jpg" />
  <p>English</p>
</div>
<div class="subject ">
  <img src="image/bio.jpg" />
  <p>Biology</p>
</div>
<div class="subject ">
  <img src="image/math.jpg" />
  <p>Mathematic</p>
</div>
<div class="subject ">
  <img src="image/sci.jpg" />
  <p>Science</p>
</div>
```