# CSS pseudo class for elements with no text

Tags: css, pseudo-class

Is there a CSS pseudo class for elements with no text nodes like so:

```
div:nocontent {
    display: none;
}
```

I know that there is the `:empty` pseudo-class but the thing I want should ignore tags...

For example:

```
<div>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Any solution for this?

**EDIT:**

For clarification it could be a syntax like this:

```
<div class="checker">
    <div class="somemarkupcontainerthatcomesfromthesystemandcantberemoved"></div>
</div>
```

And hide the whole thing like this (this would be optimal):

```
.checker:nocontent {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details because I'm not sure what is your question is?

Comment: You want a selector that will match also when there are child nodes that none of them are text nodes?

Comment: can't you do `div p:empty { display: none; }`?

Comment: In your example, do you want to target the `div` where its child `p` is empty?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624592/jquery-how-to-get-only-direct-text-without-tags-in-html should help you!

Comment: @Morpheus That doesn't target the div.

Comment: I want to check if the container has text inside and ignore any tags that may be inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `empty` check if the node is empty (so with no text and no child nodes).

There are no CSS-only options for your purpose.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to target your `div`, you need a parent selector, which does not (yet) exist, so to solve that a script is needed.

As suggested by [Hitmands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4099454/hitmands), [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624592/jquery-how-to-get-only-direct-text-without-tags-in-html) for a script sample.

When it comes to script, one have also the server side approach, where a replacement script could parse out empty tags before sending the result to the client.

If you want to target your `p`, if empty and is a child of your `div`, you can do like this.

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  min-height: 20px;
}
p {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 20px;
}
div:not(:empty) p:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p></p>
</div>
<br />
<div>
    <p>Hey</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is that i want to hide the div

Comment: @Grandy Then you need script. Follow link in my answer.

Comment: Yes seems so. I already checked the script version ... but in my case that seems not like a good solution because i don't want that my application throws javascript code into the result. I leave it as it is. Anyway thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Grandy First, why do you want them `display: none;`? ... Second, there is another approach, where you run a replacement script server side before you send the result to the client. To find empty tags would not be difficult, and when _parent selectors_ becomes available, you can just drop server side code and start using CSS.

Comment: It should be used to hide empty content columns for visitors in mobile mode (cause there create a gap destroying the layout)