# multiple div's display content with click, prevent event bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 `div's`: `div1, div2, div3`. When the user clicks on each `div`, I want to `console log` the content of that particular `div` only. I read about event bubbling and understood that the `click event` of the `child` will also be registered at the `parent` level. I tried the below code but couldn't get it to work correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#parent').on('click', 'div', function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  })
})
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
#div2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
#div3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="div1">div1
      <div id="div2">div2
        <div id="div3">div3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

1. How can I make it to print `div1` when I `click div1`, `div2` when I `click div2` and `div3` when I `click div3`?
2. is `jQuery text()` the right method to print the content? I can see it is printing spaces and all

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33592275/4628406)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not just related to event bubbling, but also the fact that the `text()` of an element contains the text of itself and all its child elements.

To do what you require you would need to `filter()` the `contents()` of the current element to retrieve only the text nodes - assuming you want to discard the text which is wrapped in any child element.

Try this:

```
$('#parent').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var nodes = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() != '';
    });
    console.log(nodes[0].nodeValue.trim());
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/f9e1rjbx/)

Comment: thank you. your code works. Seems quite a bit of code for a simple task. Would it be easier if I put the div1, div2, div3 text inside an attribute or something?  Also could you tell the corresponding method that I need to use to achieve this in plain old JS?

Comment: Putting the value in a `data-*` attribute would make the code much simpler - a one-liner as in your opening example in fact.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, according to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624592/jquery-how-to-get-only-direct-text-without-tags-in-html/33592275#33592275)

```
$('#parent').on('click', 'div', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this)
      .clone()
      .children()
      .remove()
      .end()
      .text()
      .trim()
   );
})
```