# jQuery - Display divs one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I am trying to write a simple script which will be able to read/display every single DIV one by one (without interfering with the other divs inside). Unfortunately, my idea didn't work as I thought it will. I achieved what I aimed for with `.children().remove().each` but found out that it skips the first div and deletes all the others inside. I will be really grateful if someone can help me or point what I am doing wrong.

```js
$(function Testing(){
  
    $("div").each(function(){
        var Div = $(this).text();
        alert(Div);
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="Alpha">
        Alpha
        <div id="Bravo">
            Bravo
            <div id="Charlie">
                Charlie
                <div id="Delta">
                    Delta
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to have the nested structure. If that is the case you can do it at least a couple of ways:

```js
$(function Testing() {

  $("#container div").each(function() {

    // my variation on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32170000/1544886
    var Div = $(this).contents().not($(this).children()).text();

    /* or another way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33592275/1544886
      var Div = $(this)
        .clone()    //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove()   //remove all the children
        .end()  //again go back to selected element
        .text(); 
    */

    alert(Div);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="Alpha">
    Alpha
    <div id="Bravo">
      Bravo
      <div id="Charlie">
        Charlie
        <div id="Delta">
          Delta
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added `div#container` ONLY because I didn't like the extra alerts generated from the `div`s created by having a code snippet. It's not necessary to do this in your code... you can ignore it and just use your selector `$("div")`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I realise where my mistake was. Now it is working without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

To get your desired output, you need to change your HTML so that each `div` only contains the text that you want it to output.

You'll notice two blank alerts when running this code snippet. This is because there are additional divs placed in the code snippet by SO (hidden). These extra alerts would not show in your local script.

```js
$(function Testing() {

  $("div").each(function() {
    var div_text = $(this).text();
    alert(div_text);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="Alpha">Alpha</div>
  <div id="Bravo">Bravo</div>
  <div id="Charlie">Charlie</div>
  <div id="Delta">Delta</div>
</body>
```

*Also, use descriptive variables. It is best to start this practice now (since you're learning) so you don't form bad habits. I changed `Div` to `div_text` as an example.*

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, your solution is more like bodging the answer instead of finding a solution for it.

Comment: @GeorgeStoqnov The HTML was structured strange and, since you mentioned you were learning, I thought it was open for suggestion as well.  Not trying to dodge anything :)