# How can I get the text value of <li> with nested button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the text value of the current list item.

[image]

I have tried using `$(this).text()` and `$(this).parent().text()` which both return `undefined` or `null`. I assume the solution is relatively simple but I cannot figure this one out.

Comment: Where is the code you've tried ? what you mean by _current list item_ do you have an event click ?

Comment: I tried the two jquery functions in my description to reference the <li> text value.

Comment: Add the code please to the post.

Comment: Might relate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6520267/1022914

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the onclick attribute, call the function with `this` as an argument. Then in the function, you'll have to get the entire text, and remove the button text.

This method does not rely on the ID, and can be used for any button inside of an `li` tag.

Sample HTML

```
<li id="ED_H">
  john.live.com
  <button onclick="editUnit(this)" type="button">Edit</button>
</li>
```

JavaScript

```
var editUnit = function (button) {
 var buttonText = button.innerText;
 var fullText = button.parentElement.innerText;
 var wanted = fullText.replace(buttonText, '');
 console.log(wanted);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is similar to Zakaria Acharki's answer, but this is shorter.

```js
$(function() {
  $('li').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee <button>something</button></li>
  <li>Tea <button>something</button></li>
  <li>Milk <button>something</button></li>
</ul>
```

Note that using this, will get the text inside the button as well. To avoid that, use this instead:

```js
$(function() {
  $('li').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee <button>something</button></li>
  <li>Tea <button>something</button></li>
  <li>Milk <button>something</button></li>
</ul>
```

Found in this amazing answer: [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

**EDIT:** Alternatively, you could just wrap the text in a  and get the text from that instead:

```js
$(function() {
  $('li').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).children('span').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span>Coffee</span><button>something</button></li>
  <li><span>Tea</span><button>something</button></li>
  <li><span>Milk</span><button>something</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like this answer but all the code seem messy though IMO. Easier to just wrap the text in a `<span>` and then use jQuery to find the previous `<span>` to get its content.

Comment: _I know this is similar to Zakaria Acharki's answer_, yes, the difference comes in the event delegation in my answer that handle also the dynamically created li's.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using click event `$(this).text()` should work.

```js
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', 'li', function(){
        console.log( $(this).text() );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you want to get just the direct text https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624592/jquery-how-to-get-only-direct-text-without-tags-in-html#33592275 may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `childNodes[0]` on the `li` element you want the text from, which gets the first `childNode` (text node in your example), then get the value of that node with `nodeValue` and use `trim()` to remove any whitespace.

```js
var elEd_h = document.getElementById("ED_H");
console.log(elEd_h.childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim());
```

```html
<li id="ED_H">
  john.live.com
  <button>
  Edit
  </button>
</li>
```