# Replace li text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I am trying to replace the content of li and  tags.

Tried below code.

```
   <html>
    <head>Sample</head>
   <body>
    <a href="#"><input type="checkbox" class="layer-input-filter" name="testname">Test <span class="count">5</span>      </a>

    <a href="#"><input type="checkbox" class="layer-input-filter" name="testname1">Test1 <span class="count">10</span> </a>

 <ul>
  <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Mixed assessment guidelines</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Specimen </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Plagiarism </a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Download </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Qualification update</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Specimen</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Exam guide update</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Guide </a></li>
 </ul>

  <script>
     $(document).ready(function($) {
      var value = 0.4;
      $("body").find('li').each(function (index) {
                if ($(this).text() != '') {

                    var str = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
                    var newstring =  str + str.substring(0, str.length  * value);
                    $(this).text(newstring);
                }
            });
    });
   </script>
 </body>

  </html>
```

I need to replace the text of every li inside the body. so used above jquery for it. But its not working.

Example :

```
  <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Plagiarism </a></li>
```

Should replace as

```
   <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">PlagiarismPlag </a></li>
```

First four characters of each li text. That is **Plag** in above example

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: What is the expected outcome? What is `value`?

Comment: @epascarello. first li should replace Specimen -> SpecimenSpeci

Comment: Did you actually include jQuery on the page? And what is `value`?

Comment: yes, value i am getting now Specimen for first li

Comment: You still did not answer it..... In the code `value` is NOT defined, meaning it will error out. Where do you define it.

Comment: @epascarello, I am not looking into value, need to change the text. Are you clear with the requirement?

Comment: *"clear requirement"* - nope, most definitely not clear what you're trying to achieve.  You say you want to replace "text" but the `li` contains html and it looks like you want to remove the children and replace with text, but how you determine that "Specimen" becomes "SpecimenSpeci" is really not clear.

Comment: @epascarello, there is li text right like Download, Specimen, I am trying to replace that text with appending 4more first characters for that text.

Comment: **1)** *«But its not working»* is the worst problem description you can have. **2)** The "text" in in the `<a>` elements... not in the `<li>` **3)** *«should replace Specimen -> SpecimenSpeci»* is a very strange objective... **4)** The second argument of `.substring()` cannot be a float number... That is what you have when multiplying the string length by `0.4`. and the reason why you do this is unexplained. **-- Voted to close as unclear**

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, Are you clear now?

Comment: @epascarello, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the line

```
 var str = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

The order of the functions makes the string empty in the end. If you replace it with

```
 var str = $(this).text();
```

it works.

I'm not sure what your line is trying to achieve, but the problem is there.