# How to select the plain texts inside an element using CSS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way in CSS or jQuery to select only the plain texts inside of an element?

I have an HTML code like this:

```
<div class="container">
 "some text 1"
 <div> ... </div>
 <img src="#">
 "some text 2"
 <div> ... </div>
</div>
```

and want to select only the texts that are directly inside the `container` element.

I have searched on the internet and found some solutions like using `first-child(), nth-child(), last-child()` but since the texts are not always in the specific positions; using the `*-child()` selectors don't solve my problem.

Comment: what you want to do after selecting the element

Comment: Also see: [innerText vs innerHtml vs label vs text vs textContent vs outerText](/questions/24427621)

Comment: ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624592/how-to-get-only-direct-text-without-tags-with-jquery-in-html

Comment: "what you want to do after selecting the element", @PranavCBalan after selecting I want to move it inside another element.

Comment: @Mohandes : update the question

Answer (score 1):

The [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) only works with Elements, not with Text Nodes.

In order to do that get the parent node, then get child node collection using [`childNodes` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) and finally, you can access TextNode by using index. To remove you can use [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) method or use [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) method on parent element.

```js
// get parent elemeent
let cont = document.querySelector('.container');

// get child node collection which is a live collection
let nodeCollection = cont.childNodes;

// get first child
let text1 = nodeCollection[0].textContent;
// get next child(index is 4 since there is an empty text node in between div and img)
let text2 = nodeCollection[4].textContent;

// remove the last element first since nodeCollection is live
// collection removing an element will update the index
nodeCollection[4].remove();
nodeCollection[0].remove();

console.log(text1, text2)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  "some text 1"
  <div> ... </div>
  <img src="#"> "some text 2"
  <div> ... </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myDiv">
    text 1
    <div>div text</div>
    text 2
    <span>span text</span>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $myDiv = $('#myDiv');
        var texts = [];
        for(var i = $myDiv[0].childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {// Starting from last to first, so we can remove from array without breaking JS
            if($myDiv[0].childNodes[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {// Is text only?
                texts.push($myDiv[0].childNodes[i].nodeValue);// Add this text to array
                $myDiv[0].removeChild($myDiv[0].childNodes[i]);// Remove from HTML
            }
        }
        texts = texts.reverse();
        //texts = ["text 1", "text 2"]
    });
</script>
```