# Delete item from dropdown menu with jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I found several topics here about removing items from a dropdown HTML element. However, when I try it, it fails from a script, but works in the console in browser.

The rest of the script works fine, and no errors are returned. First I have a variable with the item text, I let jQuery grab the corresponding value, and with that value I remove the item.

```js
var topicToDelete = "topic3";
console.log(topicToDelete); //returns "topic3"
var dropdownValue = $('#pick_topic option').filter(function() {
  return $(this).html() == topicToDelete;
}).val();
console.log(dropdownValue); //returns nothing
$('#pick_topic').find('option[value=' + dropdownValue + ']').remove(); //doesn't do anything
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pick_topic">
  <option value="1">topic1</option>
  <option value="2">topic2</option>
  <option value="3">topic3</option>
</select>
```

Executing the code directly doesn't work either:

```
$('#pick_topic option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == topicToDelete; }).remove(); // nothing
```

However, when I enter the lines in the browser console line by line it works and the item is removed from the dropdown menu. How can this be?

I have also looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33592275) answer.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. The `#` symbol in the html `select` element was an error of mine when writing this post. It did not appear in my original html. As for the solution: Earlier in my script I used an Ajax call and a `JSON.stringify()` method on my variable `topicToDelete`. Apparantly, JQuery couldn't handle this variable later in the .`remove()` method and subsequently returned `undefined`. I got it to work now, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you've put a `#` in the value of the `id` attribute, as a result your jQuery selector isn't matching anything. This should be removed.

```js
var topicToDelete = "topic3";
//console.log(topicToDelete); //returns "topic3"

var dropdownValue = $('#pick_topic option').filter(function() {
  return $(this).html() == topicToDelete;
}).val();

//console.log(dropdownValue); //returns nothing
$('#pick_topic').find('option[value=' + dropdownValue + ']').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pick_topic"> <!-- note: no # here -->
  <option value="1">topic1</option>
  <option value="2">topic2</option>
  <option value="3">topic3</option>
</select>
```

That being said, you're over-complicating the solution. `filter()` returns a jQuery object which you can remove directly. There's no need to get the value from that object, to then create another jQuery object pointing to the Element you already have access to. Try this:

```js
var topicToDelete = "topic3";

$('#pick_topic option').filter(function() {
  return $(this).html() == topicToDelete;
}).remove();

// alternative, using :contains which is a greedy match:
// $('#pick_topic option:contains(' + topicToDelete + ')').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pick_topic">
  <option value="1">topic1</option>
  <option value="2">topic2</option>
  <option value="3">topic3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code was good but remove `#` from `id="pick_topic"`

```js
var topicToDelete = "topic3";
console.log(topicToDelete); //returns "topic3"
var dropdownValue = $('#pick_topic option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == topicToDelete; }).val();
console.log(dropdownValue); //returns nothing
$('#pick_topic').find('option[value=' + dropdownValue + ']').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pick_topic">
    <option value="1">topic1</option>
    <option value="2">topic2</option>
    <option value="3">topic3</option>
</select>
```