# How to get childNodes of a div in cheerio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I want to get the first childNode of a div using cheerio. I am getting it using javascript dom manipulation. but can't get it on cheerio.

I have already tried it in dev tool and I got the expected result. but I want it by using cheerio.

javascript

```
document.querySelector('.title_wrapper .subtext').childNodes[0].textContent;
```

I want to get the text 'PG' from this element.

```
<div class="subtext">
    PG
    <span class="ghost">|</span>
    <time datetime="PT121M">
        2h 1min
    </time>
    <span class="ghost">|</span>
    <a href="/search/title?genres=action&amp;explore=title_type,genres&amp;ref_=tt_ov_inf">Action</a>,
    <a href="/search/title?genres=adventure&amp;explore=title_type,genres&amp;ref_=tt_ov_inf">Adventure</a>,
    <a href="/search/title?genres=fantasy&amp;explore=title_type,genres&amp;ref_=tt_ov_inf">Fantasy</a>
    <span class="ghost">|</span>
    <a href="/title/tt0076759/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ov_inf" title="See more release dates">25 May 1977 (USA)</a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it, just use [0] to get the javascript node:

```
$('.subtext')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim()
```

Comment: It still does not work

Answer (score 1):

On your specific situation, this is how to fetch data and you can apply to a massive bulk of data to your extraction:

```
    var fullText = $('.subtext').text();
    // Returns:
    // PG|2h 1min|Action,Adventure,Fantasy|25 May 1977 (USA)

    var arrSplit = fullText.split('|');
    // Splits by ('|') pipe character into an Array
    // [ 'PG', '2h 1min', 'Action,Adventure,Fantasy', '25 May 1977 (USA)' ]

    var firstChildNode = arrSplit[0];
    // Gets the "first" childNode of this specific situation
    // PG
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the parent and then remove all the child elements, leaving only the text for you to select.

```js
$(".title_wrapper .subtext")
  .clone()    //clone the element
  .children() //select all children
  .remove()   //remove all children
  .end()      //go back to selected element
  .text();    //get the text of element
```

This is an old [jQuery solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33592275/3311001).

Comment: but it gives me nothing. I got only some \n