# Create hyperlink from class jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How do you make the following become a hyperlink with Jquery?
I want to make the word link a hyperlink?

`<p>Hello World! <span class="link">Link</span>.</p>`

Comment: If you mean clickable hyperlink (with url), then you should change the markup. If you mean the pointer cursor, you can use css `cursor: pointer`.

Answer (score 0):

You could access an element by class name

```
$('.link')
```

Then change its html with your link tag and text like:

```
$('.link').html('<a href="your_link">'+ $('.link').html() + '</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do this by

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var linkClass = $(document).find(".link");
    var linkClassHTML = linkClass.html();
    linkClass.html("");
    $(linkClass).append("<a href='#>"+linkClassHTML+"</a>");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can simply use the following code that will not conflict with any other tags:

```
// Create an anchor tag pointing to the required URL if needed having the .link contents
const anchorTag = $('<a>').attr('href', 'http://EXAMPLE.com').html( $('p > .link').html() );
//Getting The direct plain text of "p" tag
const pText = $('p > .link').closest('p')
     .clone()              //clone the element
     .children()           //select all children
     .remove()             //remove all children
     .end()                // back to the selected element
     .text();              //Gets the direct "p" tag text
//Replace the "p" tag contents
$('p > .link').closest('p').html(pText).append(anchorTag);
```

Thanks to "Delgan" for the approach of getting the direct plain text of any tag can be found on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624592/how-to-get-only-direct-text-without-tags-with-jquery-in-html)