Finding all 'free' text in a HTML
I have a bunch of local html pages containing free (not enclosed in any tags) text.
<body>
<div> ... </div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.<br>
...
</body>

I'm looking for a way to select and live-manipulate these chunks of text (and only these, not text in any other container).
The page is displayed in a WebView2 browser, so the access to the DOM is limited to javascript or the WebView2.DevTools.DOM library.
I tried to find an appropriate selector, without success.
The quoted similar question does not give an answer: I need not only to extract the texts but also to modify them and write them back to the DOM.

In the example, the text is still enclosed in <body> , though. So, you should be able to select those nodes.

what you have tried so far?

@Fildor Strictly speaking, the text is of course enclosed in  tags, otherwise it wouldn't exist, but you get my meaning: I need only text not enclosed in any other tags

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59575027/16540390

This question is similar to: How to get only direct text without tags with jQuery in HTML (with vanilla option/answer). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Of course, we are speaking "strictly". That's a humongous difference. If the text were outside any tags, then this would be a whole different story. That's why it is important to be precise with language.

@jabaa The quoted answer is not relevant: I need to be able to manipulate the DOM in-place; otherwise I would've edited the files and enclose the texts in e.g.  tags.
I can of course edit the files but there are a few hundred of them so manual editing would be cruel.
In the worst case I'll use HAP to load, edit, save each file but I would rather not, as this would still need some manual tweaking/editing to cover border cases.

@alexb just to be clear: any text content is a text node .. also text content inside a regular html element. if your question is: can I select ALL the text nodes contained in the document body? the answer is yes.. but all of them will be all of them. You'll later need to filter such list based on criteria.. and you didn't state the criteria.. that in the wildest speculation could be: any free text in the body not being part of a deeper element

"I need not only to extract the texts but also to modify them and write them back to the DOM." You can write into elNodes[i].textContent and live-manipulate the text. Please first read the linked answer before you discard this solution.

@jabaa Indeed node.textContent can set the value: sorry for my  hasty conclusion.
But I can't make it work: the js code at link does not recognize tag-less text, it prints #text followed by an empty line.
const el = document.body;
const elNodes = el.childNodes;
let plainText = "";
for(i=0;i<elNodes.length;i++){
console.log(elNodes[i].nodeName);
if(elNodes[i].nodeName == '#text'){
console.log(elNodes[i].textContent);
}
}
`

Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable. You can edit your question and add formatted code there. You've asked a question and the linked answer answers your question. If you have a different question, you should describe it in the question description and not in comments. The code in your comment works for me with the HTML from your question. It prints the tag-less text: https://jsfiddle.net/zdjhxc52/

@jabaa I did some tests and now I know why the code didn't work for me: the files are "ancient", the header is

and this is the cause (I don't know enough html to understand why). Anyway, if I change the header, the script works fine.
So now it seems that I have to change the headers on all these files so, unless somebody tells me different, I'll have to do edit-save on all of them (I'll use HtmlAgilityPack to load, and modify) and, while at it, enclose the texts in paragraph tags.
My thanks to everybody who helped.
