# jQuery using nextSibling to pull out data

Tags: jquery, get, nextsibling

I am trying to only pull out the number "88" in the example below:

```
    <li>
       <a href="website">5 stars</a>
       (88)
    </li>
```

I have tried:

```
var theLi= $('li');
var theNumber = $(theLi.get(0).nextSibling).text();
```

but nothing comes up..it is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about

`var theNumber = $('li').after( $('a') ).text().replace('(','').replace(')','')`

This works.

Comment: please use jsFiddle.net to test your answers before posting them so that you don't mislead people. Your approach did not work: http://jsfiddle.net/Gq3nE/

Comment: Very close but the parentheses still remain

Comment: @Todd just use `replace`:  `$('li').after( $('a') ).text().replace('(','').replace(')','')`

Answer (score 0):

This same thing has been answered in another thread: [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

You clone the li, remove the child elements, and extract the text.

Comment: Very close but the parentheses still remain.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/bPqDR/:

```
$('li').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Comment: Very close but the parentheses still remain

Comment: Use `replace()` with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lastChild` for the given structure.

```
li.lastChild.nodeValue
```

See an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5LRW/).