# jQuery wrap div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a div around "the here is some text" area of the example below

I was thinking of doing this by finding `nav` until `menucontainer` and wrapping it in a `div`. But this isn't working.

#### HTML

```
<nav id="mainNav">
    here is some text
    <div id="menucontainer"> test</div>
</nav>
```

#### jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#mainNav").nextUntil("div#menucontainer").wrapAll( jQuery("<div></div>").addClass("newDiv") );     
});
```

The new div doesnt get appended though and I am not sure why?

Comment: _I am trying to add around the here is some text area_? WHAT!?

Comment: sorry i was trying to edit and lost internet connection - updated now - realised it didnt make much sense

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Comment: `.nextUntil()` selects elements, not text nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#mainNav").wrapInner($("<div class='newDiv' />"));

    var menucontainer = $("#menucontainer").remove();

    $("#mainNav").append(menucontainer);

});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fcm4E/)