# apply css to text that is not in any tag

Tags: php, html, css

Hi I want to apply **font-size** to **Tell us how we can improve site:** and not want to apply default **font-size** that add in **body tag** for whole site.
 If I apply css to **form#contact** so it apply on all form's elements
 I want something like this **form#contact (some magic property for text) { font-size: 16px; }**
 **Note: not with jquery**

```
<form id="contact" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/feedback">
    Tell us how we can improve site:
    <div id="edit-name-wrapper" class="form-item">
    <label for="edit-name">Your name: </label>
    <input type="text" value="" size="60" id="edit-name" name="name" maxlength="255">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why can you not add a HTML element around the text?

Comment: because i am only applying css (theming) not developing from core

Comment: Why someone **down vote** to my question? It is valid and unique question

Comment: HTML and CSS are closely coupled, in some cases you will have to modify HTML to add classes etc. This is no different.

Comment: you do realize that text-size usually inherits, so `#contact { font-size: X }` should work

Comment: @diggersworld Yes these are closely coupled but if we have this case then what to do?

Comment: @diggersworld Yes these are closely coupled but if we have this case then what to do?

Comment: @AJcodez you are right but if I also add some bg-color or color to text then?

Comment: Well you could still set a `font-size` on the form, then just make the `font-size` on the `input` and `label` elements smaller or larger, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Ok thanks to all. I ll apply css to `input` and `label` also, for the time but there should be some property like `form#contact text() { font-size: 16px; }`

Comment: @SohailAhmad `#contact { font-size: X ; color: red !important; }` ya it works

Comment: @AJcodez sorry but it also apply to other tags like I have some more elements in form `<div class="description">Solve this simple math problem and enter the result. E.g. for 1+3, enter 4.</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic property just for selecting text.

You have a few options:

1. Add `font-size` on the form element
2. Put your text into HTML elements like `<p>` tags.

In your case it might be better to use `<fieldset>` instead of that `<div>` element and then you could use a `<legend>` for the "Tell us how we can improve site" string.

Your code would then look like this:

```
<form id="contact" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/feedback">
    <fieldset id="edit-name-wrapper" class="form-item">
        <legend>Tell us how we can improve site:</legend>
        <label for="edit-name">Your name: </label>
        <input type="text" value="" size="60" id="edit-name" name="name" maxlength="255">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

However if you are unable to add elements to the existing HTML you could do the following in CSS:

```
form#contact {
    font-size: 24px; /* makes all text within form 24 pixels */
}
form#contact label,
form#contact input {
    font-size: 12px; /* makes input and label text 12 pixels */
}
```

Comment: I can't add any tag around the text

Answer (score 1):

keep that in paragraph tag and style it.

Comment: I can't add any tag around the text

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're looking for doesn't exist. Surround your text with SPAN tags

Comment: I can't add any tag around the text

Comment: oh then it's really sad :(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your "Tell us how we can improve site" inside a div and provide a class or id to it, and then in the CSS just apply font size.

Comment: I can't add any tag around the text

Comment: Are the child elements of the form tag having the font-size in percent, I mean relative?

Answer (score 0):

**Note : Never saw the without jQuery :P Gutted.**

Unfortunately I can't seem to comment, so feel like I'm stealing someone's answer

Check out this post - [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)
#

Bang in some sexy jQuery, this code wont do what you want BUT it retrieves  ONLY text not in children !

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var $tmp = $('#listItem').children().remove();
     $('#listItem').text('').append($tmp);
});
```

Edit : Adding more to this answer currnyl fiddling my Js' ;)

ok done :)

enjoy the code

http://jsfiddle.net/G7kvH/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#listItem').children().css("color","red");

});


<div id='listItem'>
    ewrt
    ert
    ert
    ert
    <div>sfdsfsdf</div>
    <div>sfdsfsdf</div>
    <div>sfdsfsdf</div>
    <div>sfdsfsdf</div>

    ert
    ert
    ert
    ert


    <div>sfdsfsdf</div>
    <div>sfdsfsdf</div>
    <div>sfdsfsdf</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and good stuff. But I think you miss this line mentioned in my question that **Note: not with jquery**