# jquery get the descendent/child of a span tag in a DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm traversing a DOM and need to get the text after the span tag

```
<span class="brand">Chanel</span>
- en cuir perle nacrée Wallet
```

I'm just starting jquery after javascript and was wondering what is the selector I need to use to select the text below the span tag?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8851526/1329367

Comment: can you put a bigger chunk of your code? the best way to get there is by addresing the container of that text.

Comment: basically here is what I'm trying to achive `var productName = $('iframe').contents().find('.brand')[0].children().innerHTML;` and it's not really working, returning "is not a method" error

Comment: Did you even try the accepted answer??

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var texts = $('span.brand').map(function () {
        return this.nextSibling.nodeValue
    });
    alert(texts[0]);
});
```

**[Fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/6KsxL/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.brand').parent().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
});
```

or

```
var txtElem = $('.brand').get(0).nextSibling;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/uJL7k/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/5dxcG/

```
$(function(){
    alert($(".brand").parent().text().replace($(".brand").text(),""));
});
```