# How to cut text in half, but leave the HTML hierarchy intact?

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a need for implementing an RSS feed where only half (or up to n characters) of article's text should be shown, but with all the HTML tags intact (such as images or youtube videos).

So for example, what if the limit of the number of characters i cut the text to is right in the middle of a code for a youtube video (which is furthermore, in a table of all things), how would i write the code to either

a) Allow the extra characters to up to the closing tag of the youtube's code AND the table, or

b) Cut the text before the table even opens

Either of those solutions is acceptable.

So for example, if i have this text in my article:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel eros eu mi estibulum blandit 
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <iframe src="http://video.example.com"></iframe>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
Phasellus sollicitudin nulla imperdiet metus ullamcorper eget ornare dui rutrum. </p>
```

And let's say that the number of characters i have to cut to fits somewhere in the middle of "http://video.example.com". Obviously, it wouldn't be good to send out just this half of the iframe tag (and half of the table).

So, what i want to get out is either

a)

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel eros eu mi estibulum blandit </p>
```

or b)

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel eros eu mi estibulum blandit 
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <iframe src="http://video.example.com"></iframe>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</p>
```

Same goes for cutting in the middle of ul lists, divs or whatever else might be in there. The only thing that's allowed to be cut in the middle of are paragraphs, because everything is in paragraphs anyway.

I hope you know what i mean, i have no idea if i explained it well.

Comment: so, what's your code so far? where are you stuck?

Comment: How are you building the output xml? why not just trim the values instead of directly plopping a lump of html into xml

Comment: @kaᵠ I don't have any code so far, I simply have no idea how to do it... I guess I'd manage substringing the text and then counting the number of opened versus closed tags to figure out where I should cut to avoid opening all the tags that didn't get closed. But I know that kind of overcomplicated solution would be too resource heavy and slow.

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè Well plopping html into xml is the client's request and since the CDATA tag allows it, it shouldn't be a problem. But i don't really understand what you meant by "just" trimming values?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the `innerHTML()` of element, create a substring until half of the text and then change it again using `innerHTML()`, traverse through all elements.

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags you can also get only the text if you want that. look at answer.

Comment: this question is mainly tagged [tag:php] and your answer looks like JS, also it's mainly an idea

Comment: @btevfik What he said ↑. I have to create an RSS feed and I cannot do that with Javascript.

Comment: @3Nex how about phpQuery ?

Comment: @btevfik Nice, never heard of it. Will give it a go.