# Replace a textNode with HTML text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textnode

I was directed to the Linkify project on GitHub (https://github.com/cowboy/javascript-linkify) for finding and "linkifying" URLs and domains just floating in text.

It's awesome! It totally works on text!

However, I'm not quite sure how to make it work on a `textNode` which has the text I want to Linkify.

I understand the `textNode` only has `textContent` since.. it's all text. Since this Linkify function returns HTML as text, is there a way to take a textNode and "rewrite" the HTML within it with the Linkify output?

I've been playing with it on JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AMhRK/9/

```js
function repl(node) {
  var nodes = node.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0, m = nodes.length; i < m; i++) {
    var n = nodes[i];
    if (n.nodeType == n.TEXT_NODE) {
      // do some swappy text to html here?
      n.textContent = linkify(n.textContent);
    } else {
      repl(n);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your example code is so messy and so much, I don't even know where to begin! Can you clean it up a little bit, and just have a normal example, and the one you want with textNode?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AMhRK/4/

Comment: @ryan it's close but you see it mangles the already properly hyperlinked URLs.

Comment: @HanletEscaño here's a "cleaned up" fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AMhRK/6/

Comment: @Jippers did you try ryan's jsFiddle? It actually works.

Comment: @HanletEscaño If you look at the output, the hyperlinks that were already in the page are now wrecked. The first twitter link for example.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/AMhRK/7/

Comment: @HanletEscaño same thing. The first hyperlink <a href="http://twitter.com">Go To Twitter</a> is no longer a link.

Comment: You are right, need another solution.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You'll need to replace the textNode with an HTML element, like a span, and then set your linkified-text as that element's innerHTML.

```
var replacementNode = document.createElement('span');
replacementNode.innerHTML = linkify(n.textContent);
n.parentNode.insertBefore(replacementNode, n);
n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
```

Comment: It's not that simple as a text node may contain a lot of "unlinkfied" elements

Comment: This seems to work! Here's a Fiddle fork with Will Scott's addition: http://jsfiddle.net/H2aHH/

Comment: this maintains the user's `Selection`, where `.replaceChild()` does not!! brilliant

Comment: var replacementNode = document.createElement('span');
var newHtml = linkify(n.textContent);
n.parentNode.insertBefore(replacementNode, n);
n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
replacementNode.outerHTML = newHtml;

Comment: @Gromo I like your solution since it doesn't end up leaving new `span` elements around.

Comment: @neaumusic it does not retain the selection (at least not in 2023)

Comment: Bless you for this answer, sincerely.

Answer (score 11):

Additionally to previous answer I propose more short way (based on jQuery):

```
$(n).replaceWith('Some text with <b>html</b> support');
```

where `n` - is textNode.

Or the [native version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith)

```
var txt = document.createElement("span");
txt.innerHTML = "Some text with <b>html</b> support";
node.replaceWith(txt);
```

where `node` is the textNode

Comment: `replaceWith()` is available as [vanilla JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith) on modern browsers (Chrome and Firefox; Edge is under development).

Comment: But in the vanilla version there is no HTML support. Tags just appear as text.

Answer (score 5):

Build on [@AlexJeffcott's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71736074/8240573) answer: Perf optimized version utilizing [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) instead of messing around with `<span>`, innerHTML and childNodes

```
const enhanceNodes = (textNodes) => {
    textNodes.forEach((node) => {
        const oldText = node.textContent;
        const newText = fancyTextTranformation(oldText);
        const fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(newText);
        node.replaceWith(fragment);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Build on Will Scott's accepted answer, if you do not wish to have to wrap everything in a span, you could do the following:

```
const enhanceNodes = (textNodes) => {
    const renderNode = document.createElement('span');
    textNodes.forEach((node) => {
        const oldText = node.textContent;
        renderNode.innerHTML = fancyTextTranformation(oldText);
        node.replaceWith(...renderNode.childNodes);
    })
}
```