# Replace An Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I want to replace something like this with jquery

```
['{star}'],['{heart}'],['{call}']
```

Whenever in **BODY** we got {star} , replace that with

```html
<i class="fa fa-star"></i>
```

Or for {hear}{call}, etc.

How can i do this?

> each element , {star} => fa fa-star, {heart}=> fa fa-heart

[EDIT SOLVED]

```html
var str = "{heart}{star}"
var updated = str.replace(/\{([^}]+)}/g, '<i class="fa fa-$1"></i>');
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\{([^}]+)}/g, '<i class="fa fa-$1"></i>');
```

Comment: Okay, what does your JQuery look like so far? I wont write the code for you, but you need to find the item you want, then replace it with the item in your array.

Comment: Might want to post a valid array

Comment: $('body :not(script)').contents().filter(function() {
 return this.nodeType === 3;
 }).replaceWith(function() {
  var finds = ['{star}','{heart}'];
  var finds_to = ['StarS','HeartS'];
  return this.nodeValue.replace(finds[i],finds_to[i]);
 });

Comment: I suppose you could parse the HTML and regex replace?

Comment: As a nudge in the right direction: `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/{star}/g, '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>');`

Comment: @Santi it's work but how can i use with array ?

Comment: each element , {star} => <i class="fa fa-star"></i> , {heart}=> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple regular expression to match anything between {}

```js
var str = "I {heart} to eat an {apple}"
var updated = str.replace(/\{([^}]+)}/g, '<i class="fa fa-$1"></i>');
console.log(updated);
```

You could also replace it with ors with known strings.

Comment: thanks,it's true , but how this can find {heart} and {apple} in body content ? :(

Comment: replace the innerHTML?

Comment: yeap replace to all of HTML content

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553280/replace-a-textnode-with-html-text-in-javascript

Comment: this will replace html content to heart and apple , but don't replace just {heart} and {apple} !

Comment: What is the actual HTML structure with the text.... If you gave the world thing, you can have a real answer....

Comment: sorry i'm new bie , sorry for my distrub :(

Comment: my question : in body we have {heart} , with jquery find {heart} and replace that to font awsome heart

Comment: I was working on a solution, during which @epascarello posted this great regex answer. I figured I shouldn't scrap everything I did, and instead incorporated his answer in mine. To avoid rewriting the entire body, you could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mc9xnn8c/ (an Inspect Element will reveal that the proper font awesome tags are in the markup)