# Check whether Text node can be replaced with span element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm writing JavaScript code that highlights text in the current document, but I don't control the document contents, so I need to be able to deal with any arbitrary HTML.

So when I've found a [Text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) DOM node, I want to [replace it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553280/replace-a-textnode-with-html-text-in-javascript) with a `<span>` element containing the text.

The problem is, while this is OK to do in most places, there are contexts where a Text node can occur but a `<span>` element cannot. The following come to mind: `<style>`, `<script>`, `<title>`, `<option>`, `<svg>`, but there are surely more. (I believe the HTML standard's "Content model" section for each element is the pertinent source; see [this example](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-option-element).) So I assume if I replaced Texts with `<span>` elements in these contexts, it would violate some well-formedness rule and could lead to undesirable behavior.

How do I check whether or not a given Text node can be replaced with a span?

Comment: I don't think any of those elements support highlighting a selection, so the problem doesn't come up. If you can highlight the text, I think you should be able to replace it with a span.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not going off the user's text selection -- the text to highlight is determined programmatically, so it could conceivably be any Text in the DOM.