# How can I remove part of a text from a selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a button trigger a function that **only** selects text that's not nested. For example, in the following code:

```
<a class="button">Hey<span>123</span></a>   <!-- alerts "Hey" -->
<a class="button">Hi<span>123</span></a>    <!-- alerts "Hi" -->
<a class="button">Hello<span>123</span></a> <!-- alerts "Hello" -->
```

Each link will call a function that alerts the text not within the `<span>`. E.g., the first link will trigger a function that alerts "Hey", the second "Hi", and the third "Hello" (illustrated in the comments above).

Naturally, I have the following code, but I can't figure out how to censor out the text within the `<span>`s  (or other elements potentially within the outer anchor element).

```
$("div.sideBox").on("click", ".button", Handler);

function Handler(event) {
    alert($(this).html());
}
```

Comment: Please correct me if i doing it wrong...

Comment: The method i used is always return a whole string , and even i replace the .html() with .val() , i have check jquery api , is there a way to retrieve the value that ignore deeper child?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Comment: @Nile Please correct or improve my question if i explain my problem in a wrong way

Comment: @Nile i am sorry for the bad question , but i think the question title should change back to (How to remove part of the returned string) , because someone(newbie like me) might crash into the same problem without knowing the nested logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work provided you put a class `.button` to anchor tags

```
<a class="button">Hey<span>123</span></a>
<a class="button">Hi<span>123</span></a> 
<a class="button">Hello<span>123</span></a>
```

Plus use javascript DOM element property `firstChild` to get the text node and `nodeValue` to get the value of it, to ignore the child `span` element's text.

```
function Handler(event) {
    alert(this.firstChild.nodeValue);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/garrn/)**

Comment: At least promote good question asking by not providing an answer to his vampire question until the OP meets minimum quality standards...

Comment: @PSL thanks i appropriate your knowledge , i was somewhere thinking of removing part of the string and should think of how to ignore the child ...

Comment: If you know what needs to be done, why'd you ask? The answer utilizes poor grammar, unspecific content, and a title that vaguely asks the question. I commented on your post because it's *you* who seems to promote this type of behavior by answering such a question. Notice I also commented on the OP.

Comment: Sure, flag it. My point is that an almost-20k user shouldn't encourage low-quality questions.

Comment: @PSL Actually, rep is an extremely important aspect here. Notice that I wouldn't (and didn't) comment on a user with a rep count such as 33. I'm simply appalled that a high-rep user would answer this question with such a low-quality format.

Comment: @PSL You simply guessed. There was no way you could have known if he was talking about *only* censoring text inside `<grey>` tags, or every type of tag. Not only that, but your answer goes to waste had I not revised the post because nobody would have found such a question on such low-quality standards. I'd generally advise not substantially editing the post like I did because users should learn how to create their own, universally-productive questions.

Comment: @PSL You definitely did. You relied on the assumption that he wanted to remove text from all elements, not just grey tags.

Comment: @PSL Not really... you vote to put it on hold so the user can learn to ask questions properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start with the HTML you have provided.  First I would remove the `<grey>` tags, as that is not a valid HTML tag.  I would put `<span>` tags around the values you want to output, this will make them easy to access in our JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<a class="stag"><span>Hey</span>123></a>
<a class="stag"><span>Hi</span>123</a> 
<a class="stag"><span>Hello</span>123</a>
```

Then use this JavaScript to return those values (using JQuery as in your example):

```
$("a.stag").click(function() {
    alert($(this).first("span").text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks i updated my html format to reach W3C standard