# Jquery output the selected html only but not its children?

Tags: jquery, html, output, children

My html:

```
<ul id="seasonsDropDown">
  <li>FALL 2013 HAUTE COUTURE
     <ul class="designers">
       <li>Alexander Wang</li>
       <li>BCBG MAX Azria</li>
       <li>Diane con Fursternberg</li>
       <li>Diane Von De</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>SPRING 2013 HAUTE COUTURE</li>
  <li>SPRING 2033 HAUTE COUTURE</li>
  <li>SPRING 2093 COUTURE</li>
```

What jQuery method should I use if I only want to select/output the word:

```
"FALL 2013 HAUTE COUTURE"
```

not the ul list?

right now if I use:

```
console.log($("#seasonsDropDown").html());
```

it would give me everything including the html.

Comment: It looks like this question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Comment: see `$('#seasonsDropDown li:first').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).text()` like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y4D25/1/

Answer (score 1):

try this i haven't checked it though..

```
$(function() {
    $('#seasonsDropDown').each(function(i, items_list){
        var myText = "";

        $(items_list).find('li').each(function(j, li){
            alert(li.text());
        })

        alert(myText);

    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#seasonsDropDown li").html().substr(0,$("#seasonsDropDown li").html().indexOf('<') );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(
  $('#seasonsDropDown li:first').contents()[0]
);
```

You could need to trim the returned string.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

The JQuery method as below

```
$("li:eq(0)").clone().children().remove().end().text()
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will need a selector in order to know which item you want to select. Your best bet is to add a selector like this:

```
$("#seasonsDropDown li").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Afterwards you will be able to select it as following:

```
console.log($("#seasonsDropDown .active").html());
```

If you just need an onClick event, you can do it as following:

```
$("#seasonsDropDown li").click(function(){
   console.log($(this).html());
});
```