# How to select own text of the element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
<div>
    <div id="t1">Text1</div> 
    <div id="t2">
        Text2 
        <ul id="t3">
            <li id="t4">Text3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select **only own** text for each element. I tried to use jQuery `text` function, but it returns the combined text content of all elements in selection:

```
t1 => Text1
t2 => Text2 Text3
t3 => Text3
t4 => Text3
```

And what I need:

```
t1 => Text1
t2 => Text2
t3 =>
t4 => Text3
```

Comment: Can you post your text function here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

I think there's your answer.

Comment: You can try to apply html function and have a look whether there is some taginside. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Freplace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.fn.ownText = function() {
    return this.eq(0).contents().filter(function() {
       return this.nodeType === 3 // && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
    }).map(function() {
       return this.nodeValue;
    }).get().join('');
}

var text = $('#t2').ownText();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5L9Ww/

A slightly faster alternative:

```
$.fn.ownText = function() {
    var children = this.get(0).childNodes, 
        l = children.length,
        a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      if (children[i].nodeType === 3) 
          a.push(children[i].nodeValue);
    }
    return a.join('');
}
```

Or a different method that accepts a glue for joining the node's values and an option for trimming the result:

```
$.fn.ownText = function(o) {
    var opt = $.extend({ glue: "", trim: false }, o),
        children = this.get(0).childNodes, 
        l = children.length,
        a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (children[i].nodeType === 3) {
          var val = children[i].nodeValue;
          a.push(opt.trim ? $.trim(val) : val);
        }
    }
    return a.join(opt.glue);
}

$('#t2').ownText({
    glue: ',',
    trim: true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
function getText(el) {
    return $(el).contents().map(function () {
        return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) ? $.trim(this.nodeValue) : undefined;
    }).get().join('')
}

$('div *').each(function () {
    console.log(this.id, getText(this))
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R2yM2/)

Answer (score 2):

Better way to do it is :

```
    $("selector").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Demo here :

http://jsfiddle.net/dM247/1/

This is not optimized version but you can optimize it :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  var n = new Array();
 $("div div, li").each(function () {

    n[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).text()

 })
 console.log(n)
```

Demo 
    http://jsfiddle.net/KVLDD/