# jQuery How to edit html text only for current level？

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DOM structure like this:

```
<div id="a">
         AA
        <span>BB</span>
</div>
```

I want to change text in div but not in span, namely change AA but keep BB, however when I try $('#a').text(), i get AABB. What's the proper way of selecting the text in div level only?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249558/how-to-select-own-text-for-element-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I created an example from this link: [How to select own text for element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249558/how-to-select-own-text-for-element-with-jquery)

I hope it helps you.

**HTML**

```
<div id="a">
         AA
        <span>BB</span>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$.fn.ownText = function() {
    return this.eq(0).contents().filter(function() {
       return this.nodeType === 3 // && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
    }).map(function() {
       return this.nodeValue;
    }).get().join('');
}

var text = $('#a').ownText();

var newText = "CC";

$("#a").html(function(i,t){
    return t.replace(text.trim(), newText)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guinatal/mHhrL/

Answer (score 0):

Please checking, this is correct

```
var child = $('#a span');
var value = "new value";
$('#a').text(value + child.html());
```

Comment: He said he needs to keep span and BB in it, therefore it is wrong answering to remove it!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to traverse the child nodes of `#a` and test to see if they are text nodes. For each text node, you will want to accumulate the inner text and return it:

**As a generic function:**

```
function getText($el, separator) {
  var s        = separator || '',
      children = $el.childNodes,
      l        = children.length,
      text     = [],
      child;

  for(; child = children[--l];)
    if (child.nodeType === 3)
      text.unshift(child.nodeValue);

  return text.join(s);
}
```

**As a jQuery plugin**

```
$.fn.getText = function(separator) {
  var s        = separator || '',
      children = this.get(0).childNodes,
      l        = children.length,
      text     = [],
      child;

  for(; child = children[--l];)
    if (child.nodeType === 3)
      text.unshift(child.nodeValue);

  return text.join(s);
}
```