# How to get nearest text inside an element?

Tags: jquery, html, text

$("#item_1").text() will return all the text under #item_1, but I need just "The First Item".

Is it possible to get text "The First Item" by using jquery?

```
<ul>    
    <li id="item_1">
        The First Item
        <ul class="ltUndertema _khKonteringUndertemaer mt2">
            <li>Item 1.1</li>
            <li>Item 1.2</li>
        </ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The easiest way will be, if you put "The First Item in the `<span> </span>`, can you do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var text = $.trim($('#item_1').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text());
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aF76V/2/).

Or:

```
var text = $('#item_1').map(function(){
    return $.trim(this.firstChild.nodeValue);
}).get().toString();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aF76V/1/).

Without jQuery:

```
var text = document.querySelector('#item_1').firstChild.nodeValue.trim();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aF76V/4/).

References:

- [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
- [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Answer (score 2):

Use contents() and find the first text node:

```
$("#item_1").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).first();
```

OR, if you **know** it's going to be the first element in that node, just the first element in the array will do:

```
var text = $("#item_1").contents()[0];
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/pLZ9q/)

Comment: I think you forgot .nodeValue her var text = $("#item_1").contents()[0].nodeValue;

Comment: @podeig True. There are enough answers here anyway that cover that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using plain old JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('item_1').childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TQhaM/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
$('#item_1').clone().find('*').remove().end().text()
```

Although this finds all text not in sub-elements, rather than just the first.  See it working in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H5Qkn/1/)