# GEB: how can I remove children elements in case of NonEmptyNavigator?

Tags: geb

The following HTML:

```
<h1>
    "Bison 120"
    <span class="prise1">#1429</span>
</h1>
```

I need to extract exactly text from H1 - "Bison 120"
Result of .text() is: "Bison 120#1429"

Very similar to this case: [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)
but in GEB solution proposed for jQuery doesn't work.

My current idea for resolution - removing children from H1 element.
Could you please help how can I remove children in GEB.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get text of the parent and then subtract text of all children from it:

```
def h1 = $("h1")

def h1Text = h1.children().inject(h1.text()) { text, child ->
    text - child.text()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works wonderful. Slightly upset not to find removing children feature in GEB. Nevertheless great solution and works for my case! :)

Comment: This is not really a Geb limitation but a WebDriver limitation because it doesn't support text nodes.