# How to use `$.trim()` on cloned element inside if statement?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check [if a paragraph (excluding any nested child tags) contain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags) -- but right now its indents give off false positives -- so how does one use `$.trim()` to get rid of them?

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/td8t4gpv/2/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>
      <a>Should not react to this</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
if($('p').clone().children().remove().end().text()) {
  console.log('WRONG! Paragraph does not have any text');
}
```

Comment: You want trim all inside a tage tex?

Comment: Essentially `.text()` should be applied to a trimmed version of `$('p')`, ie. `<p><a>...</a></p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your string to `$.trim`:

```
if(! $.trim($('p').clone().children().remove().end().text())) {
    alert('WRONG! Paragraph does not have any text');
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/td8t4gpv/3/)