# jQuery: Checking for `nodeType == 3` in a function

Tags: jquery

Expanding [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags) -- how do I turn the answer about checking for `nodeType == 3` into a function?

```js
function hasText(element) {
    element.contents().filter(function () {
        if (element.contents().nodeType == 3) {
            return true
        }
    });
}

$('p').each(function () {
  if(hasText($(this))) {
    $(this).css('border', '5px solid blue');
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Should return true -->
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello <a>there</a></p>

<!-- Should return false -->
<p><a>Hello</a></p>
<p><a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a value. Also, `Array.prototype.every` might be more appropriate than `filter`.

```js
function hasText(element) {
    return Array.prototype.every.call(element.contents(), function (c) {
        return c.nodeType === 3;
    });
}

$('p').each(function () {
    if (hasText($(this))) {
        $(this).css('border', '5px solid blue');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Should return true -->
<p>Hello</p>

<!-- Should return false -->
<p><a>Hello</a></p>
```

Comment: Greetings, and thank you very much! But like I just told David -- cases like `<p>Hello <a>there</a></p>` should also return true.

Comment: @MarkBoulder: Try `some` instead of `every`, then.

Comment: Wait, this however should return false but doesn't: `<p><a href="#"><img src="#"></a>`

Comment: @MarkBoulder: Are you sure you don’t have whitespace at the end? (If the `<p>` isn’t closed, it will.)

Comment: Oh yeah! Silly typo on my part. Yours works perfectly as well.

Comment: And it's a tad cleaner. Sorry David, looks like we have a new winner.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
function hasOnlyText(element) {
  // checking if the number of contents of the element is equal to
  // the number of contents that are textNodes:
  return element.contents().length === element.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType && this.nodeType === 3;
  }).length;
}
```

```js
function hasOnlyText(element) {
  return element.contents().length === element.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType && this.nodeType === 3;
  }).length;
}

$('p').each(function() {
  console.log(hasOnlyText($(this)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Should return true -->
<p>Hello</p>

<!-- Should return false -->
<p><a>Hello</a>
</p>
```

Alternatively, based on the clarification provided in the comments below:

```
function hasText(element) {
  return element.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType && this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim().length > 0;
  }).length;
}
```

```js
function hasText(element) {
  return element.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType && this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim().length > 0;
  }).length > 0;
}

$('p').each(function() {
  console.log(hasText($(this)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Should return true -->
<p>Hello</p>

<!-- Should return false -->
<p><a>Hello</a>
</p>

<!-- Should also return true -->
<p>Paragraph text <a>Link text</a>
</p>
```

References:

- [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Pretty nice -- but note that cases like `<p>Hello <a>there</a></p>` should also be true.

Comment: What, precisely, are you testing for?

Comment: Basically if the paragraph itself (not any of its potential children) contains any text.

Comment: Updated the answer, I think the second snippet should be what you're looking for?

Comment: It is indeed. Much obliged! minitech's answer below returns true for `<p><a href="#"><img src="#"></a>` which should be false. Yours doesn't.

Comment: Curious though, would you go with this or something like `function hasText(element) { return $.trim(element.clone().children().remove().end().text()); }`? If so, why?

Comment: I'd go with my own, but that's purely because I can read my own more clearly, and therefore understand it; yours may well be a better solution, but I can't see the problem you're trying to address with that implementation.