# jquery table filter removing too much data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My table search filter works BUT it filters too much data... I have a hidden div which has more data for the user - When you click on the user dialog popup shows up with more info.... Once the filter is used, it filters rows from the hidden div which I would like to prevent from happening...

How do I PREVENT the filter from filtering data from my hidden `<div>` ??

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/7urnro7c/1/

I'm using this code i found to filter my table:

```
$("#table tr:has(td)").each(function(){
    var t = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); //all row text
        $("<td class='indexColumn'></td>").hide().text(t).appendTo(this);
});//each tr

$("#search").keyup(function(){
    var s = $(this).val().toLowerCase().split(" ");
    //show all rows.

    $("#table tr:hidden").show();
    $.each(s, function(){
        $("#table tr:visible .indexColumn:not(:contains('" + this + "'))").parent().hide();
    });//each
});//key up.
```

By default the popup should show ALL info like so:
[image]

After using filter (typing bob) it removes rows from the popup [department, manager, employment is missing]:

[image]

Comment: So you only want it to apply to the names? E.g. if I type in 'Accounting' it shouldn't do anything?

Comment: Just a clarification, is your issue that if I type "Joe" it filters out "Kris Pokemon" because his manager isn't "Joe"?

Comment: I still want the filter to work when you type "Accounting"... but i dont want it to remove the rows from the hidden div

Comment: I think his problem is that if you enter "Accounting" and then click on Bob Smith, you don't see all the other information about Bob.

Comment: @Barmar yes.. ill post example pics now

Comment: Looking at your code it's due to your use of `text()` it gets ALL the text for the TD which includes the table HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to only get the text of the element and none of the children tags when you're doing your search. A quick search of SO gives [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

They suggest doing this:

```
$("#foo")
    .clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text();
```

For your code it would be something like:

```
$("#table tr:has(td)").each(function(){
    var t = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); //all row text
        $("<td class='indexColumn'></td>").hide().text(t).appendTo(this);
});//each tr

$("#search").keyup(function(){
    var s = $(this).val().toLowerCase().split(" ");

    //show all rows.
    $("#table tr:hidden").show();

    //Find each techname
    $("#table tr:visible .techname").each(function(){      
        //Get on the text in the element
        var text = getText(this);

        //Loop through each search term checking if the term is in the etx
        var containsText = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        {
            if(text.indexOf(s) > -1)
            {
                containsText = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        //If we didn't find the text hide the row
        if(!containsText)
        {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });//each
});//key up.


$('td.techname').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $('div#user-'+id).dialog({ modal: true, width: 400 });
    });

function getText(selector)
{
    return $(selector)
        .clone()    //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove()   //remove all the children
        .end()  //again go back to selected element
        .text()
        .toLowerCase();
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/82vanbos/4/)

Comment: The fiddle has alot of alerts :)   showing blank popup on filter

Comment: D'oh! My apologies, I told Chrome to ignore the alerts and forgot I had the alert in there. Should be correct now

Comment: I tried to fiddle around with your code but still can't get it to work ... arghh!!

Comment: Sorry @rubberchicken I realise my first attempt I misunderstood your code. I'm looking at it again right now. The issue is here `$("#table tr:visible .indexColumn:not(:contains('" + this + "'))").parent().hide();` The contains checks all text (tags included)

Comment: @rubberchicken this seems to work now [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/82vanbos/3/) can you give it a try and let me know if that's what you expect. If so I'll fix my answer :)

Comment: Ahh..one thing, if I want to filter for something that is in the hidden div (ie: i type accounting - i would want bob to show up with his info) ?

Comment: You could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/82vanbos/5/). This isn't perfect (I'm a little short on time right now) if you search "kris finance" you get everyone get both people in the Finance department. However, it should give you a basic idea of how to do what you need.