# How can i separate tags in HTML

Tags: html

I have a HTML as shown below

```
<h1 class="headerLogo headerLogoWith">First <br><i>MyLocation</i><i>- Myscreen</i></h1>
```

How can I replace the text "First" with any other data.

I tried as

```
 $('.headerLogo').text('Second');
```

But it's replacing the entire text

Or please let me know under html itself how can I separate it so that I can replace that using a specific class?

Comment: you could wrap the word in a <span> tag. easiest solution.

Comment: could you please give me sample code .

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a span tag is the easiest solution, if it is possible in your scenario.

HTML

```
<h1 class="headerLogo headerLogoWith">
    <span id='lorem'>First</span> <br>
    <i>MyLocation</i>
    <i>- Myscreen</i>
</h1>
```

JS

```
$('#lorem').text('second');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o14qmjar/

Comment: This solution looks excellent , is it possible to have dash (at Myscreen) as a span

Answer (score 0):

Add a `span` with an ID or CLASS, and replace it

```
<!-- HTML -->
<h1 class="headerLogo headerLogoWith"><span class="replace">Firts</span> <br><i>MyLocation</i><i>- Myscreen</i></h1>
<!-- JQuery -->
$(".replace").html("New text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without wrapping it in another span:

```
var html = $('.headerLogo').html();
html = html.replace('First ','Second ');
$('.headerLogo').html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go
declare span tag for your text

---

HTML:

```
<h1 class="headerLogo headerLogoWith"><span id="text">First </span><br><i>MyLocation</i><i>- Myscreen</i></h1>
```

---

JS:

```
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML="enter your text here";
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags) link that was provided by slime was really good. I also tried with jQuery how to solve this. Here is my modest answer which involves 3 lines of jQuery code (and is by no means as practical as the ones in the link above):

```js
$childElements = $('.headerLogo').children().detach();

 $('.headerLogo').text('Second');

 $('.headerLogo').append($childElements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="headerLogo headerLogoWith">First <br><i>MyLocation</i><i>- Myscreen</i></h1>
```

Above are [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) methods used before *"Second*" value is set. Finally the detached elements are appended to the `.headerLogo`.