# Get text and id value from li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been stuck in this stupid situation, i got an unorder list like this:

```js
var liList = $("#first").find("li");

var append = "";

for(var i =0; i< liList.length; i++){
  var item = $(liList);
  append += "<option value=" + item.prop("id") + ">" + item.text() + "</option";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="first">
  <li id=1>
    li 1
    <ul>
      <li id=2> li 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the text and id for each li in unorder list, but in the item.text() code part i got the current li text and the childrens text ("li1li2", "li2", etc). Any suggestion?.

Regards

Comment: `var item = $(liList[i]);`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value first node from a DOM element (which happens to be text in your case) with `.childNodes[0].nodeValue`:

```
append += "<option value=" + item.prop("id") + ">" + item[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</option";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `liList` is an array containing all the `li` elements you must iterate over every element inside you loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < liList.length; i++) {
  // retreive each element from the array
  var item = $(liList[i]);
  append += "<option value=" + item.prop("id") + ">" + item.text() + "</option>";
}
```